# How can I measure the actual memory usage of an application or process?

Tags: linux, memory, process

How do you measure the memory usage of an application or process in Linux?

From the blog article of *[Understanding memory usage on Linux](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html)*, `ps` is not an accurate tool to use for this intent.

> **Why `ps` is "wrong"**
>
> Depending on how you look at it, `ps` is not reporting the real memory usage of processes. What it is really doing is showing how much real memory each process would take up **if it were the only process running**. Of course, a typical Linux machine has several dozen processes running at any given time, which means that the VSZ and RSS numbers reported by `ps` are almost definitely *wrong*.

<sub>(Note: This question is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63166/15161) in great detail.)</sub>

Comment: This question probably belongs on serverfault.com instead nowadays, although it's telling me it's "too old to migrate".  Don't actually want to *close* it though...

Comment: Refer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-run-time-in-c

Comment: Actually `ps` doesn't show even that -- it shows virtual and resident memory numbers, where **virtual** is maximum amount of memory the process could theoretically use it it were the only process (never so), used every single page it allocated (never happens) and didn't map or unmap any pages (unlikely). While **resident** shows how much virtual memory is mapped to physical right now. Typically `virt > usage > res` however on a 64-bit system `virt ~= res*10` it's a very wide range.

Comment: The excerpt from the linked article is total nonsense. The RSS is physical memory actually used, and the VSZ may or may not translate to physical memory use even if the process was the only one running.

Answer (score 436, accepted):

With `ps` or similar tools you will only get the amount of memory pages allocated by that process. This number is correct, but:

- does not reflect the actual amount of memory used by the application, only the amount of memory reserved for it
- can be misleading if pages are shared, for example by several threads or by using dynamically linked libraries

If you really want to know what amount of memory your application actually uses, you need to run it within a profiler. For example, [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) can give you insights about the amount of memory used, and, more importantly, about possible memory leaks in your program. The heap profiler tool of Valgrind is called 'massif':

> Massif is a heap profiler. It performs detailed heap profiling by taking regular snapshots of a program's heap. It produces a graph showing heap usage over time, including information about which parts of the program are responsible for the most memory allocations. The graph is supplemented by a text or HTML file that includes more information for determining where the most memory is being allocated. Massif runs programs about 20x slower than normal.

As explained in the [Valgrind documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html), you need to run the program through Valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=massif <executable> <arguments>
```

Massif writes a dump of memory usage snapshots (e.g. `massif.out.12345`). These provide, (1) a timeline of memory usage, (2) for each snapshot, a record of where in your program memory was allocated. A great graphical tool for analyzing these files is [massif-visualizer](https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer). But I found `ms_print`, a simple text-based tool shipped with Valgrind, to be of great help already.

To find memory leaks, use the (default) `memcheck` tool of valgrind.

Newer tools I did not try myself are [HeapTrack](https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack) and the [heap profiler in gperftools](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html).

Comment: To interpret the results generated by valgrind, I can recommend alleyoop. It isn't too fancy, and tells you simply what you need to know to locate sources of leaks. A nice pair of utilities.

Comment: Item (a) isn't true.  ps shows virtual size as well as resident usage, which *is* the actually number of page frames used by the process.

Comment: Item (a) is correct.  There is a difference between pages used and memory actually allocated by the application via calls to malloc(), new, etc.  The resident usage just shows how much of the paged memory is resident in RAM.

Comment: This doesn't really tell how to get memory usage using valgrind?

Comment: It shows the amount used by the process, but not necessarily by the application.  For example, if you use malloc() to allocate a lot of memory and then free it, that memory remains on malloc's free list.  It's not used by the application, but it still belongs to the process, waiting for subsequent malloc calls to reuse it.

Comment: the default valgrind tool, memcheck, is useful for detecting memory leaks, but its not really a memory profiler. For that, you want valgrind --tool=massif.

Comment: Fine, I added some explanation on that.

Comment: convenient:

    `valgrind --tool=massif --massif-out-file=/tmp/mem_prof <executable> <arguments>`

then:

`ms_print /tmp/mem_prof | head`

Comment: "*you will only get the amount of memory pages allocated by that process but does not reflect the actual amount of memory used by the application, only the amount of memory reserved for it only the amount of memory reserved for it*". That's not true at all. RSS is pages of physical memory actually used and VSZ only represents address space reserved, not the kind of memory whose usage we measure.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I believe you misunderstood my answer. I am talking about the discrepancy between the OS level (page allocation) and the application level (malloc/free operations).

Comment: @ypnos Whatever you're talking about, what you said is not true for precisely the reason I explained. RSS is actual physical memory used by the application. And VSZ is just reserved address space. Neither is memory pages allocated.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz RSS is computed from a page count. And these pages might be actually used by the process or not (just allocated to it). I might add a proper definition of RSS when I get to it though. My answer is currently lacking information about resident/non-resident, but btw. it is just a short form of motivation for the point that these numbers don't tell what the application is really doing. Btw. a good read is https://lwn.net/Articles/230975/ (and certainly much better than the article cited in the question).

Comment: @ypnos You are wrong about RSS. RSS is actual physical pages of RAM used. It does not count memory allocated for which no pages of physical memory are mapped. (Those pages would not be resident.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry if it is still not clear, I am referring to _real_ usage by the application, not RAM allocated (mapped or not, RSS or VSZ, really not what I am talking about!). If there is plenty of RAM available, all allocated pages will be resident. However the application might not use them at all. Pages can be allocated opportunistically or not be returned after free (a very common occurence). When physical RAM fills up, RSS will shrink, although the real memory usage of the application doesn't change.

Comment: @ypnos All of that is wrong. Really. As just the simplest way to see why that's all wrong, consider an application that memory maps a 4GB file. 4GB of pages will be allocated, but no matter how much RAM you have, few if any of them will be resident because the kernel's not going to start reading the file until the pages start faulting due to access. And RSS will shrink because, in most cases, it was already *greater* than the real memory usage of the application. Pages that had no need to be in memory (because the application wasn't using them) were left there just because there was no cost.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't see how your statement is contradicting mine. I have the feeling that you are too much concerned on your point of me being "wrong" than actually reading what I am saying. My whole point here is that RSS is an improper measure for real memory usage of the application, and you are making the very same point in your last two sentences. Really, what did you even think was the reason for me to bring up the RSS shrinkage in the first place? So that you spell it out back to me to prove me "wrong" by the exact thing I am referring to? Your attitude towards me is tiresome.

Comment: @ypnos Do you agree that saying "if there is plenty of RAM available, all allocated pages will be resident" is incorrect? Do you agree that if RSS reduces, less actual physical memory is being used because of the application?

Comment: why is valgrind preferred to ps?

Comment: Valgrind only works on GNU/Linux, and possibly a handful of other very closely related OS's. Valgrind does not work for native, COMSPEC Windows environments. It doesn't even work for native macOS environments.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but then again, this question was asked for Linux specifically and also has a linux tag. Also it appears to be hard to find a freely available memory profiling solution that works on Windows outside Visual Studio. If you have one at hands, feel free to drop the knowledge here.

Answer (score 344):

Try the [pmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmap) command:

```
sudo pmap -x <process pid>
```

Comment: run with sudo or it gives no error and shows no memory consumed.

Comment: Doesn't exist on OSX (for anyone who comes here from google)

Comment: That is a full answer to the question! ps. In my shell, pmap can read the process without sudo.

Comment: Re OS X (seemingly not the OP's concern), you can see some similar data using vmmap(1)

Comment: note: gives completely different answer from `gnome-system-monitor`

Comment: I use `pmap -x 2762|grep total`  - is it possible to output in MB or GB natively using pmap utility rather than showing the result in kB?

Comment: @jcollum considering the question is about Linux, that is unsurprising.

Comment: No, it's not "unsurprising" -- OSX bash shares a lot of functions with bash in other OSes. It's helpful to know ahead of time to not try this if you are using it in OSX bash.

Comment: According to pmap my very simple Java Spring Boot application uses 20 GB of memory. I don't think that is correct.

Comment: If you own the process, the `pmap -x $PID` should work just fine. Obviously, you need `sudo` to get details of processes owned by other users.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong, or is 'pmap''s total size reported very similar to `ps`'s `VSZ` entry? We're looking for the `RSS` minus shared libs... the actual memory in use on the system by the process...

Comment: Yes, `pmap` does not know any more than `ps` does. The answer is should maybe note that.

Comment: I like this answer, I would add 'note that pmap will show a breakdown of process address space, not just a total. In terms of "actual memory usage" (which is very use-case specific) the total is unlikely to be very interesting, so focus on the detail. e.g. in my case I was interested resource use: I looked at rw, and ignored .so rw to give me an rough and relative idea of what physical memory a process might be wanting/needing'

Answer (score 210):

It is hard to tell for sure, but here are two "close" things that can help.

```
$ ps aux
```

will give you Virtual Size (VSZ)

You can also get detailed statistics from the */proc* file-system by going to `/proc/$pid/status`.

The most important is the VmSize, which should be close to what `ps aux` gives.

```
/proc/19420$ cat status
Name:      firefox
State:     S (sleeping)
Tgid:      19420
Pid:       19420
PPid:      1
TracerPid: 0
Uid:       1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:       1000    1000    1000    1000
FDSize:    256
Groups:    4 6 20 24 25 29 30 44 46 107 109 115 124 1000
VmPeak:    222956 kB
VmSize:    212520 kB
VmLck:          0 kB
VmHWM:     127912 kB
VmRSS:     118768 kB
VmData:    170180 kB
VmStk:        228 kB
VmExe:         28 kB
VmLib:      35424 kB
VmPTE:        184 kB
Threads:   8
SigQ:      0/16382
SigPnd:    0000000000000000
ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
SigBlk:    0000000000000000
SigIgn:    0000000020001000
SigCgt:    000000018000442f
CapInh:    0000000000000000
CapPrm:    0000000000000000
CapEff:    0000000000000000
Cpus_allowed:    03
Mems_allowed:    1
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    63422
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 7171
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  The question asked how to better measure memory usage by a process, given that VSZ and RSS reported in ps is misleading.  Your answer details how to look up the VSZ - the same value that was mentioned as being misleading.

Comment: @thomasrutter Yes, you are missing the original question (rev 1), it has been edited several times and is quite old (2008). The original question just asked how to measure the memory usage of a process. Feel free to edit questions and answers, though, if things are outdated. :)

Comment: note: gives completely different answer from `gnome-system-monitor`

Answer (score 178):

```
ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | \
    awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' |\
    cut -d "" -f2 | cut -d "-" -f1
```

Use this as root and you can get a clear output for memory usage by each process.

#### Output example:

```
     0.00 Mb COMMAND
  1288.57 Mb /usr/lib/firefox
   821.68 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   762.82 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   588.36 Mb /usr/sbin/mysqld
   547.55 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   523.92 Mb /usr/lib/tracker/tracker
   476.59 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   446.41 Mb /usr/bin/gnome
   421.62 Mb /usr/sbin/libvirtd
   405.11 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   302.60 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   291.46 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   284.56 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   238.93 Mb /usr/lib/tracker/tracker
   223.21 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   197.99 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   194.07 Mb conky
   191.92 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   190.72 Mb /usr/bin/mongod
   169.06 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   155.11 Mb /usr/bin/gnome
   136.02 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   125.98 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
   103.98 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
    93.22 Mb /usr/lib/tracker/tracker
    89.21 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    80.61 Mb /usr/bin/gnome
    77.73 Mb /usr/lib/evolution/evolution
    76.09 Mb /usr/lib/evolution/evolution
    72.21 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    69.40 Mb /usr/lib/evolution/evolution
    68.84 Mb nautilus
    68.08 Mb zeitgeist
    60.97 Mb /usr/lib/tracker/tracker
    59.65 Mb /usr/lib/evolution/evolution
    57.68 Mb apt
    55.23 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    53.61 Mb /usr/lib/evolution/evolution
    53.07 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    52.83 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    51.02 Mb /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
    50.77 Mb /usr/lib/evolution/evolution
    50.53 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    50.45 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    50.36 Mb /usr/lib/packagekit/packagekitd
    50.14 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    48.95 Mb /usr/bin/Xwayland :1024
    46.21 Mb /usr/bin/gnome
    42.43 Mb /usr/bin/zeitgeist
    42.29 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    41.97 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    41.64 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    41.63 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    41.55 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    41.48 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    39.87 Mb /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/chrome
    37.45 Mb /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2
    36.62 Mb /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
    35.63 Mb /usr/lib/caribou/caribou
    34.79 Mb /usr/lib/tracker/tracker
    33.88 Mb /usr/sbin/ModemManager
    33.77 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    33.61 Mb /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
    33.53 Mb /usr/sbin/gdm3
    33.37 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    33.36 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    33.23 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    33.15 Mb /usr/lib/at
    33.15 Mb /usr/lib/at
    30.03 Mb /usr/lib/colord/colord
    29.62 Mb /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
    28.06 Mb /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist
    27.29 Mb /usr/lib/policykit
    25.55 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    25.55 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    25.23 Mb /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts
    25.18 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    25.15 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    25.15 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    25.12 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    25.10 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    25.10 Mb /usr/lib/gnome
    25.07 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    24.99 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs
    23.26 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
    22.09 Mb /usr/bin/pulseaudio
    19.01 Mb /usr/bin/pulseaudio
    18.62 Mb (sd
    18.46 Mb (sd
    18.30 Mb /sbin/init
    18.17 Mb /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
    17.50 Mb gdm
    17.42 Mb gdm
    17.09 Mb /usr/lib/dconf/dconf
    17.09 Mb /usr/lib/at
    17.06 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    16.98 Mb /usr/lib/at
    16.91 Mb /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm
    16.86 Mb /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
    16.86 Mb /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm
    16.85 Mb /usr/lib/dconf/dconf
    16.85 Mb /usr/lib/dconf/dconf
    16.73 Mb /usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit
    16.69 Mb /lib/systemd/systemd
    13.13 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
    13.13 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chromium
    10.92 Mb anydesk
     8.54 Mb /sbin/lvmetad
     7.43 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.82 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.77 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.73 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.66 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.64 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.63 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.62 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.51 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.25 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     6.22 Mb /usr/sbin/apache2
     3.92 Mb bash
     3.14 Mb bash
     2.97 Mb bash
     2.95 Mb bash
     2.93 Mb bash
     2.91 Mb bash
     2.86 Mb bash
     2.86 Mb bash
     2.86 Mb bash
     2.84 Mb bash
     2.84 Mb bash
     2.45 Mb /lib/systemd/systemd
     2.30 Mb (sd
     2.28 Mb /usr/bin/dbus
     1.84 Mb /usr/bin/dbus
     1.46 Mb ps
     1.21 Mb openvpn hackthebox.ovpn
     1.16 Mb /sbin/dhclient
     1.16 Mb /sbin/dhclient
     1.09 Mb /lib/systemd/systemd
     0.98 Mb /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sda3 /media/n0bit4/Data
     0.97 Mb /lib/systemd/systemd
     0.96 Mb /lib/systemd/systemd
     0.89 Mb /usr/sbin/smartd
     0.77 Mb /usr/bin/dbus
     0.76 Mb su
     0.76 Mb su
     0.76 Mb su
     0.76 Mb su
     0.76 Mb su
     0.76 Mb su
     0.75 Mb sudo su
     0.75 Mb sudo su
     0.75 Mb sudo su
     0.75 Mb sudo su
     0.75 Mb sudo su
     0.75 Mb sudo su
     0.74 Mb /usr/bin/dbus
     0.71 Mb /usr/lib/apt/methods/http
     0.68 Mb /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
     0.68 Mb /sbin/wpa_supplicant
     0.66 Mb /usr/bin/dbus
     0.61 Mb /lib/systemd/systemd
     0.54 Mb /usr/bin/dbus
     0.46 Mb /usr/sbin/cron
     0.45 Mb /usr/sbin/irqbalance
     0.43 Mb logger
     0.41 Mb awk { hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }
     0.40 Mb /usr/bin/ssh
     0.34 Mb /usr/lib/chromium/chrome
     0.32 Mb cut
     0.32 Mb cut
     0.00 Mb [kthreadd]
     0.00 Mb [ksoftirqd/0]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/0:0H]
     0.00 Mb [rcu_sched]
     0.00 Mb [rcu_bh]
     0.00 Mb [migration/0]
     0.00 Mb [lru
     0.00 Mb [watchdog/0]
     0.00 Mb [cpuhp/0]
     0.00 Mb [cpuhp/1]
     0.00 Mb [watchdog/1]
     0.00 Mb [migration/1]
     0.00 Mb [ksoftirqd/1]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/1:0H]
     0.00 Mb [cpuhp/2]
     0.00 Mb [watchdog/2]
     0.00 Mb [migration/2]
     0.00 Mb [ksoftirqd/2]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/2:0H]
     0.00 Mb [cpuhp/3]
     0.00 Mb [watchdog/3]
     0.00 Mb [migration/3]
     0.00 Mb [ksoftirqd/3]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/3:0H]
     0.00 Mb [kdevtmpfs]
     0.00 Mb [netns]
     0.00 Mb [khungtaskd]
     0.00 Mb [oom_reaper]
     0.00 Mb [writeback]
     0.00 Mb [kcompactd0]
     0.00 Mb [ksmd]
     0.00 Mb [khugepaged]
     0.00 Mb [crypto]
     0.00 Mb [kintegrityd]
     0.00 Mb [bioset]
     0.00 Mb [kblockd]
     0.00 Mb [devfreq_wq]
     0.00 Mb [watchdogd]
     0.00 Mb [kswapd0]
     0.00 Mb [vmstat]
     0.00 Mb [kthrotld]
     0.00 Mb [ipv6_addrconf]
     0.00 Mb [acpi_thermal_pm]
     0.00 Mb [ata_sff]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_eh_0]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_tmf_0]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_eh_1]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_tmf_1]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_eh_2]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_tmf_2]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_eh_3]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_tmf_3]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_eh_4]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_tmf_4]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_eh_5]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_tmf_5]
     0.00 Mb [bioset]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/1:1H]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/3:1H]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/0:1H]
     0.00 Mb [kdmflush]
     0.00 Mb [bioset]
     0.00 Mb [kdmflush]
     0.00 Mb [bioset]
     0.00 Mb [jbd2/sda5
     0.00 Mb [ext4
     0.00 Mb [kworker/2:1H]
     0.00 Mb [kauditd]
     0.00 Mb [bioset]
     0.00 Mb [drbd
     0.00 Mb [irq/27
     0.00 Mb [i915/signal:0]
     0.00 Mb [i915/signal:1]
     0.00 Mb [i915/signal:2]
     0.00 Mb [ttm_swap]
     0.00 Mb [cfg80211]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/u17:0]
     0.00 Mb [hci0]
     0.00 Mb [hci0]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/u17:1]
     0.00 Mb [iprt
     0.00 Mb [iprt
     0.00 Mb [kworker/1:0]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/3:0]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/0:0]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/2:0]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/u16:0]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/u16:2]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/3:2]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/2:1]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/1:2]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/0:2]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/2:2]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/0:1]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_eh_6]
     0.00 Mb [scsi_tmf_6]
     0.00 Mb [usb
     0.00 Mb [bioset]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/3:1]
     0.00 Mb [kworker/u16:1]
```

Comment: Any way to filter the list so as to only have processes that use more than say 25% of memory for say 30s ? I'm trying to see running away processes, like the Chrome browser when using a PHPEclipse debugger.

Comment: Great! But the loop should start from `x=2` to also output pid and user.

Comment: How to get PID in the output ?

Comment: This provides a nicely formatted output, but it doesn't answer the question. It lacks the summing part, as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55171/137608 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55171/137608

Comment: but this output isn't summed. you need to sum MB by hand

Comment: Sorting with `ps` doesn't work for threads. So it's better to use `sort` like this: `ps -eo size,pid,user,command | sort -nr | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f MiB ", hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' | cut -d "" -f2 | cut -d "-" -f1`

Answer (score 160):

In recent versions of Linux, use the *smaps* subsystem. For example, for a process with a PID of 1234:

```
cat /proc/1234/smaps
```

It will tell you exactly how much memory it is using at that time. More importantly, it will divide the memory into private and shared, so you can tell how much memory your *instance* of the program is using, without including memory shared between multiple instances of the program.

Comment: i guess `pmap` is a simpler interface to it.

Comment: This answer is gold though for embedded systems that don't have pmap

Comment: This provides plenty of information.  What can I grep for to get the actual total RAM being used?

Comment: You can use awk to add up all the PSS entries: `awk '/^Pss:/ {pss+=$2} END {print pss}' < /proc/1234/smaps`

Answer (score 148):

Use [**smem**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/smem.8.html), which is an alternative to *[ps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_(Unix))* which calculates the USS and PSS per process. You probably want the PSS.

- **USS** - Unique Set Size.  This is the amount of unshared memory unique to that process (think of it as *U* for *unique* memory).  It does not include shared memory.  Thus this will *under*-report the amount of memory a process uses, but it is helpful when you want to ignore shared memory.
- **PSS** - Proportional Set Size.  This is what you want.  It adds together the unique memory (USS), along with a proportion of its shared memory divided by the number of processes sharing that memory.  Thus it will give you an accurate representation of how much actual physical memory is being used per process - with shared memory truly represented as shared.  Think of the *P* being for *physical* memory.

How this compares to RSS as reported by **ps** and other utilities:

- **RSS** - Resident Set Size. This is the amount of shared memory plus unshared memory used by each process.  If any processes share memory, this will *over*-report the amount of memory actually used, because the same shared memory will be counted more than once - appearing again in each other process that shares the same memory.  Thus it is *fairly* unreliable, especially when high-memory processes have a lot of forks - which is common in a server, with things like Apache or PHP ([FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI)/FPM) processes.

Notice: smem can also (optionally) output graphs such as pie charts and the like.  IMO you don't need any of that.  If you just want to use it from the command line like you might use `ps -A v`, then you don't need to install the Python and Matplotlib recommended dependency.

Comment: One critical point about RSS is that most applications these days share a lot of code pages.  Every shared library (e.g. libc and libstdc++) will be counted for every process using it.  And if there are multiple instances of a process running, all of that code will be double-counted.

Comment: Precisely, which is why RSS over-reports in term of actual physical memory per process.

Comment: smem is what I needed. By running it with -t every time I start a new process instance, I can see the memory that each instance consumes. For chrome: smem -t -P '/opt/google/chrome'

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding documentation for smem.. does it output in bytes, kilobytes, or megabytes by default??

Comment: Kilobytes.  It's weird that it doesn't clarify that in the docs, but that is at least consistent with the way `top`, `free` and `ps` report memory use.

Comment: TL;DR: USS = Amount of physical memory that will be freed if process is killed, PSS = Amount of physical memory that this process needs from the system if no existing processes will be killed, RSS = Amount of physical memory that is accessible by this process (but not always exclusive access).

Comment: this one is so far the only one to match the output of `gnome-system-monitor`. just `smem   -k | grep $PID` will do the job, my vote.

Comment: This is a great tool. `sudo smem -up` shows the actual per-user memory consumption of the system in percent (PSS column).

Comment: If you're running a process inside a container, that container will be loading libraries from within it's own image (which is a separate filesystem tree). The memory pages from these libraries would not be shared with other containers unless they are sharing the same backing volume right? That could mean using containers will result in a lot more memory usage. Unless it's possible to share volumes between containers. What about the case where multiple containers don't share volumes but are built from the same base layer? Would that enable page sharing in memory?

Comment: Yes any form of virtualisation or containers will significantly increase physical RAM requirements. There would be challenges in sharing pages between systems that should have no knowledge of each other, it'd be a copy on write system but what if a process in a container goes to write to a page it already considers allocated but the write fails because the host can't re-allocate. Maybe someone's already solved this, I don't know.

Comment: @ZN13 I was wondering the same thing and ended up running `smem -k`, which prints a unit after the numbers.

Answer (score 141):

There isn't any easy way to calculate this. But some people have tried to get some good answers:

- [ps_mem.py](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py)
- [ps_mem.py at GitHub](https://raw.github.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py)

Comment: nice outputs a clean listing of memory and process

Comment: Very nice, with quite smart grouping.

Comment: Yeap, quite nice indeed. I find `ps_mem` and `smem` very useful for end-user measures, while eg. `pmap`'s very detailed output is geared toward devs... allows to retrieve Firefox's Memory usage for each fonts, addons, libs for ex. Thank you all exp. @Bash, @thomasruther.

Comment: this one is so far the only one to match the output of `gnome-system-monitor`

Answer (score 99):

Use `time`.

Not the *Bash* builtin `time`, but the one you can find with `which time`, for example `/usr/bin/time`.

Here's what it covers, on a simple `ls`:

```
$ /usr/bin/time --verbose ls
(...)
Command being timed: "ls"
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.00
Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2372
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 1
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 121
Voluntary context switches: 2
Involuntary context switches: 9
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 256
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

Comment: I am also. It's the way I use to profile tasks in powercron.eu :)

Comment: `brew install gnu-time` then use `gtime` if you are on macOS.

Comment: Drawback : Wont get the results till the process completes its execution. Cannot be used for real-time monitoring of running process.

Comment: /usr/bin/time -f '%M'

Comment: You can also invoke it using \time (with a backslash to prevent using the shell's internal time).

Comment: Prefixing with backslash is interesting... but the other way is run it as `command time`.

Answer (score 47):

Beside the solutions listed in the answers, you can use the Linux command "top". It provides a dynamic real-time view of the running system, and it gives the CPU and memory usage for the whole system, along with for every program, in percentage:

```
top
```

to filter by a program PID:

```
top -p <PID>
```

To filter by a program name:

```
top | grep <PROCESS NAME>
```

"top" provides also some fields such as:

VIRT -- Virtual Image (kb): The total amount of virtual memory used by the task

RES -- Resident size (kb): The non-swapped physical memory a task has used ; RES = CODE + DATA.

DATA -- Data+Stack size (kb): The amount of physical memory devoted to other than executable code, also known as the 'data resident set' size or DRS.

SHR -- Shared Mem size (kb): The amount of shared memory used by a task. It simply reflects memory that could be potentially shared with other processes.

Reference [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for ;)

Answer (score 41):

This is an excellent summary of the tools and problems: [archive.org link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110614010958/http://ktown.kde.org/%7Eseli/memory/analysis.html)

I'll quote it, so that more devs will actually read it.

> If you want to analyse memory usage of the whole system or to thoroughly analyse memory usage of one application (not just its heap usage), use **exmap**. For whole system analysis, find processes with the highest effective usage, they take the most memory in practice, find processes with the highest writable usage, they create the most data (and therefore possibly leak or are very ineffective in their data usage). Select such application and analyse its mappings in the second listview. See exmap section for more details. Also use **xrestop** to check high usage of X resources, especially if the process of the X server takes a lot of memory. See xrestop section for details.
>
> If you want to detect leaks, use **valgrind** or possibly **kmtrace**.
>
> If you want to analyse heap (malloc etc.) usage of an application, either run it in **memprof** or with **kmtrace**, profile the application and search the function call tree for biggest allocations. See their sections for more details.

Comment: exmap abandoned from 2006 and doesn't build

Answer (score 25):

I am using [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) and there's this wonderful package called `ps_mem`:

```
ps_mem -p <pid>
```

#### Example Output

```
$ ps_mem -S -p $(pgrep firefox)

Private   +   Shared  =  RAM used   Swap used   Program

355.0 MiB +  38.7 MiB = 393.7 MiB    35.9 MiB   firefox
---------------------------------------------
                        393.7 MiB    35.9 MiB
=============================================
```

Comment: `ps_mem` looks good and is available on CentOS as well :-)

Comment: This this script is absolutely amazing. Does exactly what I needed. You can quickly and easely get it on ubuntu with this long but simple command if you need:
`sudo curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pixelb/ps_mem/master/ps_mem.py -o /usr/local/bin/ps_mem.py; sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/ps_mem.py; sudo apt install python -y -qq; sudo ps_mem.py`

Comment: Nowadays you probably want to use `smem -k` instead.

Comment: this one INSANE script, I can not upvote this enough!

Answer (score 23):

There isn't a single answer for this because you can't pin point precisely the amount of memory a process uses. Most processes under Linux use shared libraries.

For instance, let's say you want to calculate memory usage for the 'ls' process. Do you count only the memory used by the executable 'ls' (if you could isolate it)? How about libc? Or all these other libraries that are required to run 'ls'?

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00ccb000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x06bc7000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x00230000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x00162000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00b40000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00cb4000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00b1d000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00229000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00cae000)
libsepol.so.1 => /lib/libsepol.so.1 (0x0011a000)
```

You could argue that they are shared by other processes, but 'ls' can't be run on the system without them being loaded.

Also, if you need to know how much memory a process needs in order to do capacity planning, you have to calculate how much each additional copy of the process uses. I think */proc/PID/status* might give you enough information of the memory usage *at* a single time. On the other hand, [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) will give you a better profile of the memory usage throughout the lifetime of the program.

Comment: i am trying to find how much memory a process is taking on a VM and want to use that to setup memory limit in kubernetes, i agree on this answer, so will be using the memory shown by `pmap`

Answer (score 19):

If your code is in C or C++ you might be able to use `getrusage()` which returns you various statistics about memory and time usage of your process.

Not all platforms support this though and will return 0 values for the memory-use options.

Instead you can look at the virtual file created in `/proc/[pid]/statm` (where `[pid]` is replaced by your process id. You can obtain this from `getpid()`).

This file will look like a text file with 7 integers. You are probably most interested in the first (all memory use) and sixth (data memory use) numbers in this file.

Comment: Note that this is not supported on all platforms.

Comment: According to the Linux man page (http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage), getrusage is part of the SVr4, 4.3BSD and POSIX.1-2001 specs (noting that POSIX only specifies the utime and stime fields.)  I wouldn't expect it to work on non-UNIX platforms (except, perhaps, via an environment like Cygwin that provides UNIX capabilities for other platforms.)

Comment: @DavidC. the OP is asking about Linux.

Comment: @CashCow, did you mean `getpid()`, because I do not know of a `getprocessid()` function in C/C++ under Linux.

Answer (score 14):

**Valgrind** can show detailed information, but it **slows down** the target application significantly, and most of the time it changes the behavior of the application.

**Exmap** was something I didn't know yet, but it seems that you need a **kernel module** to get the information, which can be an obstacle.

I assume what everyone wants to know with respect to "memory usage" is the following...
In Linux, the amount of physical memory a single process might use can be roughly divided into following categories.

- **M.a anonymous mapped memory**
- .p private

  - .d dirty == malloc/mmapped heap and stack allocated and written memory
  - .c clean == malloc/mmapped heap and stack memory once allocated, written, then freed, but not reclaimed yet
- .s shared

  - .d dirty == **malloc/mmaped heap could get copy-on-write and shared among processes** (edited)
  - .c clean == **malloc/mmaped heap could get copy-on-write and shared among processes** (edited)
- **M.n named mapped memory**
- .p private

  - .d dirty == file mmapped written memory private
  - .c clean == mapped program/library text private mapped
- .s shared

  - .d dirty == file mmapped written memory shared
  - .c clean == mapped library text shared mapped

Utility included in Android called **showmap** is quite useful

```
virtual                    shared   shared   private  private
size     RSS      PSS      clean    dirty    clean    dirty    object
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- ------------------------------
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 0:00 0                  [vsyscall]
       4        4        0        4        0        0        0                         [vdso]
      88       28       28        0        0        4       24                         [stack]
      12       12       12        0        0        0       12 7909                    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
      12        4        4        0        0        0        4 89529                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION
      28        0        0        0        0        0        0 86661                   /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 87660                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MEASUREMENT
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 89528                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TELEPHONE
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 89527                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_ADDRESS
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 87717                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_NAME
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 87873                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_PAPER
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 13879                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 89526                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MONETARY
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 89525                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_TIME
       4        0        0        0        0        0        0 11378                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_NUMERIC
    1156        8        8        0        0        4        4 11372                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_COLLATE
     252        0        0        0        0        0        0 11321                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_CTYPE
     128       52        1       52        0        0        0 7909                    /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
    2316       32       11       24        0        0        8 7986                    /lib/libncurses.so.5.7
    2064        8        4        4        0        0        4 7947                    /lib/libdl-2.11.1.so
    3596      472       46      440        0        4       28 7933                    /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
    2084        4        0        4        0        0        0 7995                    /lib/libnss_compat-2.11.1.so
    2152        4        0        4        0        0        0 7993                    /lib/libnsl-2.11.1.so
    2092        0        0        0        0        0        0 8009                    /lib/libnss_nis-2.11.1.so
    2100        0        0        0        0        0        0 7999                    /lib/libnss_files-2.11.1.so
    3752     2736     2736        0        0      864     1872                         [heap]
      24       24       24        0        0        0       24 [anon]
     916      616      131      584        0        0       32                         /bin/bash
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- ------------------------------
   22816     4004     3005     1116        0      876     2012 TOTAL
```

Answer (score 14):

Three more methods to try:

1. `ps aux --sort pmem`
   It sorts the output by `%MEM`.
2. `ps aux | awk '{print $2, $4, $11}' | sort -k2r | head -n 15`
   It sorts using pipes.
3. `top -a`
   It starts top sorting by `%MEM`

*(Extracted from [here](http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/05/linux-uso-de-memoria-por-proceso.html))*

Comment: `top` and probably the others don't give an accurate representation of the memory actually used by the process. For example, I have 64GiB of RAM, and I have 10 `postgres` processes each reporting 16GiB RES and 25% MEM. Of course, they can't all be using 25%... Each also has 15GiB SHR, and it seems they're sharing that.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The premise was: *"ps is not an accurate tool to use for this intent."*

Answer (score 9):

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# Returns total memory used by process $1 in kb.
#
# See /proc/NNNN/smaps if you want to do something
# more interesting.
#

IFS=$'\n'

for line in $(</proc/$1/smaps)
do
   [[ $line =~ ^Size:\s+(\S+) ]] && ((kb += ${.sh.match[1]}))
done

print $kb
```

Comment: ksh is a standard shell. It might not be installed by default on _linux_ distros for desktop users or for minimalistic purposes, but it's only one command away in almost any unix-/linux OS. (i.e. on all BSDs, on all real UNIX, on RHEL, on SLES, on Debian, on Ubuntu, on OSX)

Comment: This file is accessible, by default, only to root user.

Comment: Following is just the above rewritten into `sed | awk` and works in Busybox v1.23.2:

`sed -n 's/^Size:\s\+\(\S\+\) .*/\1/p' /proc/$1/smaps | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

Comment: @Catskul - The POSIX standard specifies its standard shell as a strict subset of the Korn shell, an enhanced version of the Bourne shell.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using [htop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop); it's a very good console program similar to Windows [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager).

Comment: I used `htop` and is better than top but still it will show you all the threads from different apps without grouping them making it almost as useless as top.

Comment: $ htop -p $(pgrep <your process name> | xargs | tr ' ' ',')

Answer (score 7):

Note: **this works 100% well only when memory consumption increases**

If you want to monitor memory usage by given process (or group of processed sharing common name, e.g. `google-chrome`, you can use my bash-script:

```
while true; do ps aux | awk ‚{print $5, $11}’ | grep chrome | sort -n > /tmp/a.txt; sleep 1; diff /tmp/{b,a}.txt; mv /tmp/{a,b}.txt; done;
```

this will continuously look for changes and print them.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Get [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind). Give it your program to run, and it'll tell you plenty about its memory usage.

This would apply only for the case of a program that runs for some time and stops. I don't know if Valgrind can get its hands on an already-running process or shouldn't-stop processes such as daemons.

Comment: No, it's not possible to "attach" valgrind to a running process. That's by design.

Answer (score 6):

A good test of the more "real world" usage is to open the application, run `vmstat -s`, and check the "active memory" statistic. Close the application, wait a few seconds, and run `vmstat -s` again.

However much active memory was freed was in evidently in use by the application.

Comment: How would this be better than ps?? It comes with all the limitation of ps and is even more inaccurate...

Comment: A typical Unix system has many process starting and finishing all the time.  You cannot predict your free RAM.

Answer (score 6):

The below command line will give you the total memory used by the various process running on the Linux machine in MB:

```
ps -eo size,pid,user,command --sort -size | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; printf("%13.2f Mb ",hr) } { for ( x=4 ; x<=NF ; x++ ) { printf("%s ",$x) } print "" }' | awk '{total=total + $1} END {print total}'
```

Answer (score 6):

If the process is not using up too much memory (either because you expect this to be the case, or some other command has given this initial indication), and the process can withstand being stopped for a short period of time, you can try to use the gcore command.

```
gcore <pid>
```

Check the size of the generated core file to get a good idea how much memory a particular process is using.

This won't work too well if process is using hundreds of megabytes, or gigabytes, as the core generation could take several seconds or minutes to be created depending on I/O performance.  During the core creation the process is stopped (or "frozen") to prevent memory changes.  So be careful.

Also make sure the mount point where the core is generated has plenty of disk space and that the system will not react negatively to the core file being created in that particular directory.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you use atop. You can find everything about it on [this page](http://www.atoptool.nl/downloadatop.php). It is capable of providing all the necessary KPI for your processes and it can also capture to a file.

Comment: To show the PSIZE ["proportional memory size of this process (or user)] launch atop using `atop -R`.  To show a per-user summary push `p`, to sort by memory usage push 'M' from within atop.  This gives similar numbers than smem.

Comment: What is *"KPI"* in this context?

Answer (score 4):

If you want something quicker than profiling with Valgrind and your kernel is older and you can't use smaps, a ps with the options to show the resident set of the process (with `ps -o rss,command`) can give you a quick and reasonable `_aproximation_` of the real amount of non-swapped memory being used.

Answer (score 3):

Another vote for [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) here, but I would like to add that you can use a tool like [Alleyoop](http://alleyoop.sourceforge.net/) to help you interpret the results generated by Valgrind.

I use the two tools all the time and always have lean, non-leaky code to proudly show for it ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this shell script to check [memory usage by application in Linux](http://www.linoxide.com/linux-shell-script/linux-memory-usage-program/).

It is also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/nixsavy/shell-scripts/blob/master/memstat.sh) and in a version [without paste and bc](https://github.com/asmund1/shell-scripts/blob/master/memstat.sh).

Answer (score 3):

Given some of the answers (thanks thomasrutter), to get the actual swap and RAM for a single application, I came up with the following, say we want to know what 'firefox' is using

`sudo smem | awk '/firefox/{swap += $5; pss += $7;} END {print "swap = "swap/1024" PSS = "pss/1024}'`

Or for libvirt;

`sudo smem | awk '/libvirt/{swap += $5; pss += $7;} END {print "swap = "swap/1024" PSS = "pss/1024}'`

This will give you the total in MB like so;

`swap = 0 PSS = 2096.92`

`swap = 224.75 PSS = 421.455`

Tested on ubuntu 16.04 through 20.04.

Comment: "smem" was used in [thomasrutter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-can-i-measure-the-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process/13754307#13754307).

Comment: This didn't really work for me — the reported RAM value was still the same as the one given by the KDE system monitor. [Lokendra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711589/476920) worked like a charm though.

Answer (score 2):

While this question seems to be about examining currently running processes, I wanted to see the peak memory used by an application from start to finish. Besides [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind), you can use [tstime](https://bitbucket.org/gsauthof/tstime), which is much simpler. It measures the "highwater" memory usage (RSS and virtual). From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18858/15954).

Comment: Most applications - that is, those that use malloc() and malloc-like memory libraries - don't return pages to the OS until proess termination.  So the amount you see with PS (or any other tool that doesn't dig into the process's heap) will be the high-water mark.

Comment: What is *"RSS"* in this context?

Answer (score 0):

*Based on an answer to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641553/how-to-find-the-memory-consumption-of-a-particular-process-in-linux-for-every-5/29090375#29090375).*

You may use [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) to get the memory and CPU usage of a process in a particular device on the network :)

#### Requirements:

- The device running the process should have `snmp` installed and running
- `snmp` should be configured to accept requests from where you will run the script below (it may be configured in file *snmpd.conf*)
- You should know the process ID (PID) of the process you want to monitor

#### Notes:

- ***HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfCPU*** is the number of centi-seconds of the total system's CPU resources consumed by this process. Note that on a multi-processor system, this value may increment by more than one centi-second in one centi-second of real (wall clock) time.
- ***HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem*** is the total amount of real system memory allocated to this process.

### Process monitoring script

```
echo "IP address: "
read ip
echo "Specfiy PID: "
read pid
echo "Interval in seconds: "
read interval

while [ 1 ]
do
    date
    snmpget -v2c -c public $ip HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfCPU.$pid
    snmpget -v2c -c public $ip HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem.$pid
    sleep $interval;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

/prox/xxx/numa_maps gives some info there: N0=??? N1=???. But this result might be lower than the actual result, as it only counts those which have been touched.

Answer (score 0):

I found [heaptrack](https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack) much easier to use than valgrind.

```bash
sudo apt install heaptrack heaptrack_gui
heaptrack my-program args
heaptrack_gui *.zst
```

[image: heaptrack_gui snapshot]

Answer (score -2):

Use the in-built *System Monitor* GUI tool available in Ubuntu.

Comment: At least since 16.04 that works very well. It's very much like top though, the memory used is not extremely precise...