# How to get info on how much RAM does your app eat?

Tags: c++, boost

So I need it crossplatfom way, may be using boost, or at least for windows. So how to get info on how much RAM does your app eat ?

Comment: It is a meaningless value that greatly varies, depending on how many other processes run.  Only virtual memory size can say something.

Comment: "How much RAM does X use" is a question without an answer. Processes can share memory (for example, DLLs), memory can be swapped out, memory can be allocated within a process, but not actually using RAM or swap, etc. You need to refine what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get memory usage at run time in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-run-time-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, use the Task Manager; for Linux, use `top`. You're much better off having the OS tell you rather than trying to guess within your application.

Answer (score 2):

Try `getrusage()` on *NIX and `GetProcessMemoryInfo()` on Windows.

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrusage.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

On Windows with Visual Studio you can use [CRT Debug Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28VS.80%29.aspx) functions.  `_CrtMemDumpStatistics` could be used to print useful stats.  `_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince` lists all the objects allocated between checkpoints.  There is more useful stuff like memory leak detection (`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks`).  It's also possible to take snapshots with `_CrtMemCheckpoint` and compare differences with `_CrtMemDifference` later on.

It's also possible to redefine `new` to get more detailed information with CRT debug functions.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new new(_CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#endif
```

**Note:** This only tracks the CRT allocations. To get the entire process memory information you could use `GetProcessMemoryInfo`.

Comment: this
#define new new(_CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
is undefined behavior.
Redefinition of reserved words is explicitly prohibited by the C++ Standard.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: Well, this is what Microsoft suggests to do.  It's also possible just add those parameters manually to every `new` in the code, but that would quite painful.  I think rules can be bent sometimes.  It's just a debug test version after all.  No need to release that.

Comment: It's not portable. It is perfectly well-defined by MSDN, just not by ISO. However, do understand that it's defined as that macro, with all associated nastiness. For instance, it will affect your attempt to declare an `operator new` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to use http://valgrind.org/ to test the overall performance of my applications, VERY USEFUL FOR MEMORY LEAK DETECTION! If your looking for simple runtime info both Linux's TOP command and Window's task manager are very easy to use.