# Want to notedown CPU usage and Memory Usage of my C program

Tags: c, linux, embedded, cpu, cpu-usage

Here i made one function which calculates CRC16 of any file . i made this function and program in C .

Now i want to find out CPU usage and Memory usage of my this CRC16 calculation function.

I know about `top` command. here i have no more time to see this thing on other tab and its not user friendly to use this.

i found one link but i cant get more idea about this.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux)

Is there any function which do these things and give me result?

Please Any body help me to find out this thing.

Comment: Try `time` and `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: @KerrekSB But how can i use this?

Comment: If your program is `prog`, run it as `time prog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in `man 2 getrusage` for more info.

I expect that `ru_idrss` is what you need for memory usage. It should be filled in in more recent versions of the Linux kernel. Or you could use procps and get info from the /proc directory. The difference in `ru_utime` before and after the calculation will give you the CPU time

There is more info in this question: [How to get memory usage at run time in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-run-time-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answers above, you can also use `pmap`, `mmap`, `oprpfile` and, my personal favorite, `perf`, found in linuxtools. Hope it helps.

Comment: But how i can use give me Example

Answer (score 0):

If you are picky about performances and work on x86 or x64, you can try [valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) and its *callgrind* tool, as well as its more precise (but harder to grasp) *cachegrind* alternative.

After installing it through your distribution's package manager, it is simply a matter of:

```
valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./a.out
valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out
```

Note that you can use the visual tool [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to visialize the performance data easily. I linked to the wikipedia article for valgrind, because it's succint and quite complete. [The official Valgrind website is here](http://valgrind.org/).

I usually improve my hot loops performance by some orders of magnitude using this tool!