# How to get memory information on Linux system?

Tags: c++, linux

How to get the total memory, used memory, free memory from C++ code on Linux system?

Comment: Read the pseudo-files in /proc.  They have a manpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate, depending on whether you want system-wide or process-specific information: [How to get memory usage at run time in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/669438/464709)

Answer (score 0):

Run your program through `valgrind`. For a program called `foo`, for example:

```
valgrind foo
```

It'll run the program in a harness that keeps track of memory use and print out that information after the program terminates.

If you don't have `valgrind` installed for some reason, you should be able to find it in your distro's package repository.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [Chris Stratton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429063/chris-stratton), you can -on Linux- query a lot of system information in `/proc/` so read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html); which contain textual pseudo-files (a bit like pipes) to be read sequentially. These are not real disk files so are read very quickly. You'll need to open and close them at every measurement.

From inside a process, you can query its [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) using `/proc/self/maps` -and `/proc/self/smaps`; outside of that process, for another process of pid 1234, use `/proc/1234/maps` & `/proc/1234/smaps`; you can get system wide memory information thru `/proc/meminfo`

So try the following commands in a terminal:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
cat /proc/$$/maps
cat /proc/$$/smaps
cat /proc/self/maps
```

to understand more what they could give you.

Be aware that `malloc` and `free` (used by `new` and `delete`) are often requesting space (from the kernel) using syscalls like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) but are managing previously `free`-d memory to reuse it, so often don't release memory back to the kernel with `munmap`. Read wikipage on [C memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management). In other words, the *used* heap is not accessible outside the process (since some *unused*, but reusable for future `malloc`-s, memory remains `mmap`-ed). See also [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) and [malloc_stats(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html).

As [Justin Lardinois answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26436548/841108), use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect memory leaks.

[Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) is a good book to read. It has several related chapters.