# How to programatically get the memory usage of the current program?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, rhel

I would like to get some information about the memory usage of my C++ program. The way I do this is by accessing `/proc/self/stat` and printing the virtual and resident set size.

You can find an example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-runtime-using-cplusplus).

Is this a good way to go? How accurate is the information I am accessing*?

Could someone recommend a better way to measure memory usage programmatically?

*Asking, because I get unexpected, sudden jumps of mem usage. My expectation was that the information is perfectly accurate.

**OS:** I am running inside a docker container, which is based on RHEL.

Additional info: If I limit the memory usage of the container with `docker run -m`, the printed memory is greater than the limit I set.

Comment: This is *very* dependent on operating system, so please [edit] your question to clearly state that (for example by adding it as a tag).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get memory usage at runtime using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-runtime-using-c)

Comment: @usr It kindof does. The solution there is pretty much what I was using. But I got the strange result, when using this method. This is why I was looking for better ways to do it

Answer (score 2):

> How to programatically get the memory usage of the current program?

There is no standard way to get memory usage of a program in C++.

The concept of "memory usage" itself is somewhat vague and can mean different things. Depending on what you mean, there may or might not be a system specific way to get the information.

> The way I do this is by accessing `/proc/self/stat`
>
> Is this a good way to go?

I don't think so. As far as I know, /proc filesystem is not portable. Use the `getrusage` function on POSIX systems.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it

Comment: The OP specified linux specifically RHEL. So maybe portability is not an issue