# Is my approach to log memory utilization severely incorrect?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am running C++ code on Ubuntu. I need to log current memory utilization. After quick reading [linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html), I came up with following:

```
double getTotalMemory() {
    std::ifstream meminfo("/proc/meminfo");
    if (!meminfo) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening /proc/meminfo." << std::endl;
        return -1.0;
    }

    double totalMemory = 0.0;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(meminfo, line)) {
        if (line.find("MemTotal:") == 0) {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::string memType;
            int memSize;
            iss >> memType >> memSize;
            totalMemory = static_cast<double>(memSize);
            break;
        }
    }

    meminfo.close();
    return totalMemory;
}

double availableMemoryKB = static_cast<double>(sysconf(_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES) * sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)) / 1024.0;

// Calculate memory utilization percentage
double memoryUtilization = 100.0 - (availableMemoryKB / totalMemoryKB) * 100.0;
```

However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669438/how-to-get-memory-usage-at-runtime-using-c) answer gives many different approaches. Am I severely wrong with my approach?

Comment: The Q&A you link to seems to be about logging memory utilization for the current process so it's not the same as what you are doing.

Comment: Aah, I see. But is my logic look OK?

Comment: If you want to get the system totals, I guess it could work. You could probably simplify it by using `MemTotal`, `MemFree` and `MemAvailable` directly.