# How to log the memory consumption on Linux?

Tags: linux, logging, memory-consumption

Is there any ready-to-use solution to log the memory consumption from the start of the system? I'd like to log the data to simple text file or some database so I can analyze it later.

I'm working on Linux 2.4-based embedded system. I need to debug the problem related to memory consumption. My application automatically start on every system start. I need the way to get the data with timestamps from regular intervals (as often as possible), so I can track down problem.

The symptoms of my problem: when system starts it launched my main application and GUI to visualize the main parameters of the system. GUI based on GTK+ (X server). If I disable GUI and X server then my application works OK. If I enable GUI and X server it does not work when I have 256 MiB or 512 MiB of physical memory installed on the motherboard. If I have 1 GiB of memory installed then everything is OK.

Comment: This looks similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process

Comment: Does your app at least run for some time before crashing ?

Comment: Yes, previous versions runs OK in the same system. Now we develop new version, and start hitting this problem.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A small script like

```
rm memory.log
while true; do free >> memory.log; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: indeed, this is very close to what I need. I can add timestamps myself.

Comment: `free -s 1 > memory.log`; this doesn't incur in the costs of launching a new process every second. It doesn't have timestamping, though. (I know this is an old post, but I was looking for the same thing, and so will others).

Comment: In some versions of free it is needed that you specify the number of times you want to print with -c due to a bug. Otherwise it shows the error    free: seconds argument `1' failed

Comment: Thanks @Sputnik, also you have to specify the count before the seconds. E.g. `free -h -c 3 -s 1`

Comment: .@hirschhornsalz - Is it possible to read any specific `sysfs` and then log memory usage? I am using a program written in `C` and would like to log using it with minimal overhead?

Comment: free -s 5 -m> memory.log how to add timestamp before every lie in this log?

Comment: @7wick [Apply this answer to add timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26797)

Answer (score 66):

The following script prints time stamps and a header.

```bash
#!/bin/bash -e

echo "      date     time $(free -m | grep total | sed -E 's/^    (.*)/\1/g')"
while true; do
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') $(free -m | grep Mem: | sed 's/Mem://g')"
    sleep 1
done
```

The output looks like this (tested on Ubuntu 15.04, 64-bit).

```bash
      date     time          total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
2015-08-01 13:57:27          24002      13283      10718        522        693       2308
2015-08-01 13:57:28          24002      13321      10680        522        693       2308
2015-08-01 13:57:29          24002      13355      10646        522        693       2308
2015-08-01 13:57:30          24002      13353      10648        522        693       2308
```

Comment: For non english users It's important to use `LANG=C`. Some translations of free translate the `Mem:` part as `Mem.` (with dots) breaking the grep command

Answer (score 9):

I am a big fan of logging everything and I find it useful to know which processes are using the memory and how much each process is using (as well as sumary statistics). The following command records a top printout ordered by memory consumption every 0.5 seconds:

```
top -bd0.5 -o +%MEM > memory.log
```

Just note that the log file will grow a lot faster than if you only store the total memory utilization statistics so be sure you don't run out of disk space.

Comment: Thank you, this was much more informative than free.

Answer (score 7):

There's a program called

```
sar
```

on *nix systems.  You could try to use that to monitor memory usage.  It takes measurements at regular intervals.  Do a

```
man sar
```

for more details.  I think the option is -r for taking memory measurements, -i to specify the interval you'd like.

Comment: Definitely more powerful than the other proposed solutions, although a bit more cumbersome to set up.

Comment: e.g. `sar -r 2 5` for reporting every two seconds five times. It also allows you to export and read output file in binary format.

Answer (score 5):

You could put something like

```
vmstat X >> mylogfile
```

into a startup script. Since your application is already in startup you could just add this line to the end of the initialization script your application is already using.
(where X is # of seconds between log messages)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, though I need to log the data more often then every second.

Answer (score 5):

I think adding a crontab entry will be enough

```
*/5 *  *  *  *  free -m >> some_output_file
```

There are other tools like [SeaLion](https://sealion.com), [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/), [Server Density](http://serverdensity.com) etc which will almost do the same but are much easier to install and configure. My favorite is SeaLion, as it being free and also it gives a awesome timeline view of raw outputs of common linux commands.

Comment: +1 for Sealion, teh fastest signup/setup EVER. The whole thing I think took me about 6 seconds - I typed in my email, a password. Pasted a single command into ssh and boom my stats appeared.

Answer (score 1):

To periodically log the memory usage efficiently, I combined [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904948/209246) here with [a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42911402/209246) to only retain the top-K memory-using processes.

`top -bd 1.5 -o +%MEM | grep "load average" -A 9 > memory_usage.log`

This command will record, every 1.5s, the top header information and the 3 highest memory-consuming processes (there's a 6-line offset for `top`'s header information). This saves lots of disk space over recording `top`'s information for every process.

Answer (score 0):

So I know that I am late to this game, but I just came up with this answer, as I needed to do this, and really didn't want the extra fields that **`vmstat`**, **`free`**, etc... all will seem to output without excess filtering.  So here is the answer that I came up with:

```
top -bd 0.1 | grep 'KiB Mem' | cut -d' ' -f10 > memory.txt
```

OR:

```
top -bd 0.1 | grep 'KiB Mem' | cut -d' ' -f10 | tee memory.txt
```

the standard output from ***`top`*** when ***`grep`*** ing  with ***`Kib Mem`*** is:

```
KiB Mem : 16047368 total,  8708172 free,  6015720 used,  1323476 buff/cache
```

By running this through cut, we filter down to literally just the number prior to **used**

The user can indeed modify the ***`0.1`*** to another number in order to run different capture sample rates.  In my case I wanted to use ***`top`*** also because you can run memory stats faster than 1 second per capture, as you can see here I wanted to capture a stat every 1/10th of a second.

***NOTES:***
It does turn out that piping through ***`cut`*** cause MASSIVE delay in getting anything out to file.  As we later found out, it is much faster to leave out the ***`cut`*** command during data acquisition, then perform the cut command on the output file later.
Also, we had no need for timestamps in our tests.

This thus looks as follows:

***Begin Logging:***

```
top -bd 0.1 | grep 'KiB Mem' | tee memory_raw.txt
```

***Exit Logging:***

```
ctrl-z (to exit logging)
```

***Filter:***

2 levels of cut (filtering), first by comma, then by space.  This is due to the alignment of ***`top`*** and provides much cleaner output:

```
cut memory_raw -d',' -f3 | tee memory_used_withlabel.txt
cut memory_used_withlabel.txt -d' ' -f3 | tee memory_used.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I let this run for 10 seconds and the output file is empty.

Comment: @rayryeng - My answer is decently old, I wonder if a newer version of the commands with the newer linux variants have different switch options.