# Transpose output of free

Tags: linux, logging, memory, raspbian, free

I am interested in logging the output of free and add a timestamp. I would like an output similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761478/906592) however I would like the final output to have these columns

```
date, time, Mem. total, Mem. used, Mem. free, Swap total, Swap used, swap, free.
```

So that the two types of memory appear in the same line. In contrast free reports mem and swap in 2 lines.

If this is not possible the other option would be

`date`, `time`, `type of memory`, `total`, `used`,  `free`

where `type of memory` would be `mem` or `swap`.

Is something like this possible? As a script so as to call it every 5 min with cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work for you?

```
(date "+%Y%m%d,%H%M%S"; free -wm )| awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==1{printf "%s",$0} NR==3{$1="";printf "%s,",$0} NR==4{$1="";printf "%s",$0} END{print ""}'
```