# RED5/Java memory limit

Tags: memory-management, jvm, red5

I have RED5 installed on my virtual server (I need it for my chat application), which has 1GB of RAM memory. When I start my RED5 it takes approx. 1GB immediately after start and thats a problem, because then my whole site is very site. Iam sure it does not use the whole 1GB, so I need a solution how could I limit it to lets say 700MB.

I have tried such things in red5.sh:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m $LOGGING_OPTS $SECURITY_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS"
```

But without success.

EDIT - forgot to mention, i use debian on my VPS.

Comment: then check with "top" or "ps" command and check which one takes more memory. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process