# How can I get the memory of one process in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux: How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process)

Why I use 'top' in Linux to show my memory of one process,I get that the storage of the process do only increase and do not decrease except I close the all process.I don't know why,though I use 'free' only behind 'malloc'.
How can I get the correct actual REAL-TIME storage of my process?
thanks all.

Comment: Do you want to get the memory usage of that process via C API from within your program which could be that process or via a shell command?

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer i think

Comment: @Sam, yes, but sebif is just two points away from being able to post comments...

Comment: ... and now, enough that you can re-post this as a comment. :)

Comment: I get from the shell command 'top' that the my C process is taking more and more storage of the OS when I take some actions,and I know that I have 'free' all the 'malloc'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that on a modern operating system this is very difficult.

Memory that is free()ed is not actually returned to the OS
until the process terminates, so many cycles of allocating
and freeing progressively bigger chunks of memory will cause
the process to grow. ([via](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.solaris/process-memory-usage-vsz-and-rss/237933))

[This question has been already answered in more detail on another SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process) You might find your answer there.

Answer (score 8):

find the pid, if its running as the same user, use "ps aux", otherwise use "ps ax", then execute this:

```
cat /proc/<PID>/status
```

this should be all u want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the size of your allocations, your memory may or may not be returned to the OS. If you're allocating *large* things (see `MMAP_THRESHOLD` in `malloc(3)`), things that take many pages of memory, glibc will use `mmap(2)`'s `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag for the allocation; when you `free(3)` this object, glibc can return the page to the OS, and your memory usage will go down.

You can tune `MMAP_THRESHOLD` down using `mallopt(3)` if you wish.

If you have many smaller allocations, your memory may be *fragmented* enough that `free(3)` cannot actually free up an entire page that could be returned to the OS. You might have relatively little in *use* on a given page, but the entire page is still allocated against your process, and it replaces an entire page's worth of data from other processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this other question really answers this in detail.

Adding to [what sarnold says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409090/296974), it could be helpful to `free()` in the opposite order as `malloc()` - especially for the smaller memory chunks. Then the heap can shrink again from the end...

In order to verify that, you should, in a test program, call `void *sbrk(intptr_t increment);` with an increment of 0 - then it tells you the current value of the heap - and output it in order to see its changes. If you do it correctly and in the right oder, the glib should call `brk()` to increase the heap and eventually shrink it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pmap and the id process:

```
    1:   init [3]
```

001c3000    100K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so

001dc000      4K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so

001dd000      4K rwx--  /lib/ld-2.5.so

001e0000   1256K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.5.so

0031a000      8K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.5.so

0031c000      4K rwx--  /lib/libc-2.5.so

0031d000     12K rwx--    [ anon ]

0034b000      8K r-x--  /lib/libdl-2.5.so

0034d000      4K r-x--  /lib/libdl-2.5.so

0034e000      4K rwx--  /lib/libdl-2.5.so

006f2000    236K r-x--  /lib/libsepol.so.1

0072d000      4K rwx--  /lib/libsepol.so.1

0072e000     40K rwx--    [ anon ]

0073a000     84K r-x--  /lib/libselinux.so.1

0074f000      8K rwx--  /lib/libselinux.so.1

00fff000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]

08048000     32K r-x--  /sbin/init

08050000      4K rw---  /sbin/init

09c0f000    132K rw---    [ anon ]

b7fed000      8K rw---    [ anon ]

bfd87000     84K rw---    [ stack ]

total     2040K