# How to find the memory consumption of a particular process in linux for every 5 seconds

Tags: linux, memory, process, pid

I just want to know how to find the memory consumption of a particular process for particular time(say 5 seconds)

I am new to linux. So, detailed steps of doing that will be appreciated

Comment: Could you define what does "memory consumption for a particular time" means to you?? Remember that a memory zone which has been `free`-d is often still (internally) allocated by the system (because it will be re-used and given back at some later `malloc`). You may want to use `valgrind`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may use SNMP to get the memory and cpu usage of a process in a particular device in network :)

**Requirements:**

- the device running the process should have snmp installed and running
- snmp should be configured to accept requests from where you will run the script below(it may be configured in snmpd.conf)
- you should know the process id(pid) of the process you want to monitor

**Notes:**

- ***HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfCPU*** is the number of centi-seconds of the total system's CPU resources consumed by this process.  Note that on a multi-processor system, this value may increment by more than one centi-second in one centi-second of real (wall clock) time.
- ***HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem*** is the total amount of real system memory allocated to this process.

**

**Process monitoring script:**

**

```
echo "IP: "
read ip
echo "specfiy pid: "
read pid
echo "interval in seconds:"
read interval

while [ 1 ]
do
    date
    snmpget -v2c -c public $ip HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfCPU.$pid
    snmpget -v2c -c public $ip HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunPerfMem.$pid
    sleep $interval;
done
```

Comment: memory output will be in Kbytes

Answer (score 29):

Use `top -p PID` where PID is the process ID. Information about the process should be displayed, including percent of system memory used. Type `d` and an integer in seconds to change the refresh rate.

Comment: For retrieving PID of an process, one can use ps -aux | grep "process" where "process" is the name of process you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

use [watch](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_watch.htm) to periodically execute your script. here is an example:

```
watch 'cat /proc/status' --interval=5

watch 'ps aux' --interval=5
```

Comment: if i want to check for a particular process say pid = 12468 ?

Comment: Presently i am using this piece to get the CPU usage and the other info of a particular process.                                        unix95= ps -p 12994 -o pid,sz,pcpu,ruser,args,time,stime,pmem,etime I want to check this for every time interval of 5 seconds

Comment: use cat /proc/pid/status or whatever

Comment: Regardless of the `watch` interval, `ps u -p PID` will not refresh it's values as fast as `top`

Comment: Or use `cat /proc/12488/maps` if you want a better understanding of the address space of process 12488...

Answer (score 3):

This previously posted question:

[How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process)

seems like it may thoroughly address your question.

edit: My personal favorite Linux utility for checking the resource usage of processes is top, though it can be misleading for reasons that are explained in the question I linked.

Comment: in the reply that you have given it is found that we can see process and their starting time, cpu usage and all. In addition to that i want to check the process memory usage for 5 seconds

Comment: Do you mean the *change* in memory usage over that period? My first instinct might be to write a simple script to run a command that outputs a process's memory usage every 5 seconds, and continuously compute the delta.