# OSX - how to get memory usage of NSTask?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, process

I need to start a external program and wait until it ends. After it was running I nead peak memory usage and CPU time oder CPU tiks.

How can I do this in C / Objective-C on OSX 10.11?

I looked at NSTask, but I have no idea how to get peak memory usage and CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the PID by calling `-processIdentifier` and then use Mach's `task_info()` function to get the information you seek.  See: [Memory used by a process under mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389581/memory-used-by-a-process-under-mac-os-x)

I believe task info should be available until the process is waited, so just be sure to do that after the process finishes.