# Does delete[] really work in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I have a function which uses 0.5 MB memory each time I run it. So I decided to investigate it step by step by watching the Windows task manager at the same time. I noticed after these lines:

```
int **banned;
banned=new int*[vertices];
for(i=0;i<vertices;i++)
    banned[i]=new int[k_colors];
```

It uses 0,5 MB memory. Then I decided to delete it before the `return` line:

```
for(i=0;i<vertices;i++)
   for(j=0;j<k_colors;j++)
       delete []banned[j];
   delete[]banned;
```

It was 8,5 MB memory using beginning of the function. After allocation, it became 9 MB, but after the delete part, it was still 9 MB. And I execute this function in the whole program 1000 times. Then it is getting killed by OS. Any idea why is that and how can I solve it?

EDIT: Here the `main()` part:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    input();
    initialize();
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_GENERATION; i++)
    {
        parents = selection(TS);
        population = cross_over(parents, PC);
        mutation(PM);
        elite=tabu_search(population);
        elitism(); //270 MB memory using each time.

    }
fclose(pFile);
return 0;
}
```

Above, in `elitism()` function's first line are allocation part, and last lines are `delete` part.

Comment: `delete[]` doesn't _return the memory to the OS_.

Comment: Ok, then how can I do that?

Comment: Depends on what your OS offers for such. But I doubt there is a suitable way.

Comment: Same thing happens in unix too. I uploded my work to there. after a few minutes it gets killed. the terminal just says `Killed`

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it returns the memory to the OS. What matters is that the memory gets returned in such a way that future allocations can re-use that memory. Whether that's by returning it to the OS or by internally marking it as unused is irrelevant. Either way, you're right that repeatedly running that same function should not cause a repeated increase in memory use, that does appear to indicate a leak somewhere.

Comment: @hvd I think you are right but I am about the being blind here. I watched every step in the task manager and it happens because of this allocation. Do you think that I have to move the allocation part to out of the general loop in the `main()`? is it works?

Comment: Have you tried running the program through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: maybe dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323037/returning-dynamically-allocated-memory-back-to-os-without-terminating-the-progra

Comment: you are not `delete` the same things you are `new`ing in this code, btw

Comment: @WhoCares There's not enough in your question for me to give a more useful answer. (Well, I see there's enough for Matt McNabb to spot a problem, but not for me. :)) If you have a complete sample program that you can put in your question that repeatedly allocates and then deallocates memory, shouldn't fail unless the first iteration fails, but does fail, much later, that would really help get a good answer.

Comment: @WhoCares - Does your program leak memory?  If not, then there is nothing to worry about.  The C++ heap manager is what is controlling whether memory is actually returned to the OS or not.  If you called that function 1,000 times where you allocate and deallocate the memory, the memory allocated doesn't increase after the first time (or it shouldn't).

Comment: @GoBusto I don't know what it is, but certainly I am going to.

Comment: @hvd I updated it. I hope it works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but it is increasing

Comment: @MattMcNabb I am about the try what you said. hold on.

Comment: @WhoCares - That is because your code is wrong.  You loop one way to allocate, then something totally different to deallocate.  In other words, you lost track and didn't reverse your steps properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok then, what can I do to do it properly?

Comment: @WhoCares - The answer given to you below by MattMcNabb fixes the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie aha. ok I have forgotten to try iy. Now it worked. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `delete[]` properly you should delete the same things that you new'd:

```
for(i=0;i<vertices;i++)
    delete [] banned[i];

delete[] banned;
```

Your "process getting killed" is probably because your original code caused crazy amounts of undefined behaviour, deleting the same pointer multiple times and so on.

This version may or may not release memory to the operating system; that is a decision made by your compiler/library and the operating system.  On some systems, the memory may appear to still be allocated to your process, but the OS will be able to claim it if another process needs it.

If you call the same function over and over it should not accumulate memory though; the previously `delete`'d blocks can answer the `new` call.

Comment: Hey again. This worked in windows very good but in linux it returns seg. fault. Do you know why?

Comment: You have a bug in the code that you didn't post. Try debugging your program. In linux use gdb and valgrind.

Comment: Now I debugged it by valgrind. Here is the thing; I deleted the code you gave me. It worked in linux well. With this shape, I ran it with valgrind, and it gave an error which was about the `fscanf()`. However, They are very different part of program. I mean `fscanf()` and `delete` part. And also, valgrind didn't tell me anything about the code you gave me if I add it again. It still says sth about `fscanf()`. Do you think they are  related somehow?

Comment: btw I used it with `valgrind --leak-check=yes`line.

Comment: start a new question `fscanf` has nothing to do with this one. It sounds like you have heap corruption . Make sure you post a MCVE otherwise people are just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory in your application, the C++ runtime will ask the OS for "more memory". Under the assumption that you will allocate more memory again, "if there isn't HUGE amounts of memory freed - hold on to it". In other words, "task manager" and other such tools are not ideal for understanding exactly how much memory is ACTUALLY allocated in your application.

However, `delete []` does indeed work in all commercial grade released compiler environments.

The problem in your code is that your are deleting things you didn't allocate.

You call `delete []` for each of the `vertices` and once for the whole array, matching your `new` calls. [Every place you have a `new`, there should be exactly the same `delete` - same number of times, same pointer]

It is also possible that you are "fragmenting" the memory - for example something like this

```
size_t s = 100;
for(;;)
{
    int *p = new int[s];

    ...
    delete [] p; 
    s += 10;
}
```

So, the freed memory is "too small" for the next allocation.

Of course, this whole mess could be avoided by using

```
vector< vector <int> > banned(vertices);
for(i=0;i<vertices;i++)
   banned[i].resize(k_colors);
```

And now the memory used gets cleaned up automatically.

Comment: If by "work" you mean "impossible to use without introducing endless hideous bugs and strictly inferior in every way to other approaches", then yes. That's a rather strange definition of "work", though.

Comment: Uh, that's a different point. The fundamentals for most of the container types is `new` and `delete` [although typically wrapped into an allocator class, but that's just sugar on top]