# Get precise (or reasonably accurate) memory and time consumption of an application

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, memory

I am trying out a clustering tool developed by my senior and I don't have the source code. My problem is, I am unable to measure the memory and time requirement for a given clustering task.

I tried `htop`, but most of my clustering tasks run for only 1-2 seconds and thus, I am unable to monitor the process in `htop`. Further, if a clustering task takes reasonable amount of time (~40s), I am able to monitor the process in `htop`. However, it just shows 0.1% of MEM regardless of the input matrix file size (25MB and 58MB). How can I get a precise (or reasonably accurate)  measurements.

I run the tool as follows:

`./tool <clustering_algo_name> <input_matrix_file> <output_file>`

I am running this on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/

Comment: "I am trying out a clustering tool developed by my senior and I don't have the source code" sounds like a horrible idea. Have you tried asking why source code isn't shared between colleagues working with the same stuff?