# Why does R use so much memory when using read.csv()?

Tags: r, csv, memory-management, file-io

I'm running R on linux (kubuntu trusty). I have a csv file that's nearly 400MB, and contains mostly numeric values:

```
$ ls -lah combined_df.csv 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 naught101 naught101 397M Jun 10 15:25 combined_df.csv
```

I start R, and `df <- read.csv('combined_df.csv')` (I get a 1246536x25 dataframe, 3 int columns, 3 logi, 1 factor, and 18 numeric) and then use the script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) to check memory usage:

```
R> .ls.objects()
         Type  Size    Rows Columns
df data.frame 231.4 1246536      25
```

Bit odd that it's reporting *less* memory, but I guess that's just because CSV isn't an efficient storage method for numeric data.

But when I check the system memory usage, `top` says that R is using 20% of my available 8GB of RAM. And `ps` reports similar:

```
$ ps aux|grep R
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
naught1+ 32364  5.6 20.4 1738664 1656184 pts/1 S+   09:47   2:42 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
```

1.7Gb of RAM for a 379MB data set. That seems excessive. I know that [`ps` isn't necessarily an accurate way of measuring memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process), but surely it isn't out by a factor of 5?! Why does R use so much memory?

Also, R seems to report something similar in `gc()`'s output:

```
R> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used  (Mb)
Ncells   497414  26.6    9091084 485.6  13354239 713.2
Vcells 36995093 282.3  103130536 786.9 128783476 982.6
```

Comment: You have no other objects loaded?  Have you tried restarting your R session?  It may be there is a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: @iShouldUseAName: This is with a fresh R session, with no other objects loaded.

Comment: When R takes memory from the system, it rarely gives it back, even if it is no longer using all that memory.

Comment: @JeremyS: but this is a clean session. Are you saying that that extra ~1.3GB of memory is due to memory used in the `read.csv()` function? e.g. `read.csv()` doesn't do garbage collection well?

Comment: Have you employed both of the pieces of advice in `?read.csv` regarding reducing memory usage? There's a whole section on memory usage there that explicitly states: "These functions can use a surprising amount of memory when reading large files.".

Comment: @JeremyS: that's entirely untrue, and is the entire point of garbage collection. This question is answered in [FAQ 7.42](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-R-apparently-not-releasing-memory_003f).

Comment: @joran: YES! `a <- read.csv('combined_df.csv', nrows=1500000, colClasses=unlist(lapply(read.csv('combined_df.csv', nrows=1), class)))` *significantly* reduces over-all memory usage (by a factor of 3-4). If you want to post an answer along those lines, I will accept it. I will also change change the question title to reflect the problem.

Comment: @JeremyS: so I take it `ps` *is* effectively out by a factor of 5 then.. But does that mean that that memory that's allocated by the system, but no-longer used by R will be re-used by R first, before more is allocated?

Comment: `gc()` doesn't always work like you expect. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#gc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in my comment above, there is a section in the documention `?read.csv` entitled "Memory Usage" that warns that anything based on `read.table` may use a "surprising" amount of memory and recommends two things:

1. Specify the type of each column using the `colClasses` argument, and
2. Specifying `nrows`, even as a "mild overestimate".

Comment: Also note [FAQ 7.42](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-R-apparently-not-releasing-memory_003f).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you just want to know how R works or if you want an alternative to `read.csv`, but try `fread` from `data.table`, it is much faster and I assume it uses much less memory:

```
library(data.table)
dfr <- as.data.frame(fread("somecsvfile.csv"))
```