# Why there is big difference in memory usage between ps and free?

Tags: linux, memory, operating-system, system-administration

```
# ps hax -o rss|paste -d+ -s|bc; free
3963568
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8176380    7602512     573868     119048     680236     501084
-/+ buffers/cache:    6421192    1755188
Swap:      4199420     327820    3871600
```

Sum of RSS from `ps` shows `3963568` while `free` tells `6421192`. What else goes to `free` and how can I track it with `ps` or other tools? Is it fragmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted at [How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process):

> Why ps is "wrong"
>
> Depending on how you look at it, ps is not reporting the real memory usage of processes. What it is really doing is showing how much
>   real memory each process would take up if it were the only process
>   running. Of course, a typical Linux machine has several dozen
>   processes running at any given time, which means that the VSZ and RSS
>   numbers reported by ps are almost definitely "wrong".

So your ps command will tend to OVERCOUNT the memory used by processes, as it double-counts memory that is shared.

On the other hand, I can see you are looking at the correct line of the free output which discards the memory used for buffers/cache. You need to look in `/proc/meminfo` to see what is using up most of the discrepancy in RAM, as discussed at https://serverfault.com/questions/240277/slab-uses-88gb-of-128gb-available-what-could-cause-this.

Slab cache is separate from the buffers/cache reported by free, so assuming it is responsible for most of the discrepancy you can see what it is used for in `/proc/slabinfo`. If it's dentries (`dentry_cache` line) or inodes (there are many `*inode_cache` lines), you can use the following to free up the RAM:

```
sync; echo 2 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

to get rid of them.