# Total/Free virtual memory for a single process in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory, virtual

I need to monitor:

- physical memory
- swap memory
- virtual memory

for the current process. Total and available (free).

Physical and swap I acquire with no problems whatsoever using `sysinfo` stucture, I can get used virtual memory from e.x. `/proc/self/statm`...

> ...but I still need total and/or free virtual memory **for the current process**. How to accomplish this?

This is purely Linux related question (in Win it's easy). Used distros: Ubuntu, Fedora.

> EDIT:
>   Maybe it will be easier to understand my question, when I say that I'm trying to acquire equivalent of `ullTotalVirtual` and `ullAvailVirtual` from [Windows MEMORYSTATUSEX structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366770(v=vs.85).aspx) from [GlobalMemoryStatus()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx) on Linux systems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process)

Comment: Please read carefully instead of giving random links.
I DO HAVE actual virtual memory usage.
What I need is total virtual memory for the process (free + used) or available virtual memory for the process (free).

Comment: What does "free virtual memory for the process" mean? Slack space in internal allocators? Overcommitted mmap address space? What?

Comment: `ullAvailVirtual`
`The amount of unreserved and uncommitted memory currently in the user-mode portion of the virtual address space of the calling process, in bytes.`

Answer (score -1):

Some weeks ago a published the following tiny library: https://sourceforge.net/projects/meminfo/

Maybe it helps solving your problem

Comment: Unfortunately it's about memory usage as well, which is NOT what I'm looking for. It uses `/proc/self/smaps`.

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for then? You wrote physical, swap and virtual Memory for the current process.

Comment: It's not an easy question, so carefully reading question is a really important thing.

I wrote in question:
_but I still need total and/or free virtual memory for the current process. How to accomplish this?_

Comment: @MKK It's been quite some time, had you found your answer for this? I am looking for the same but couldn't find anything on total and/or free virtual memory for the current process on web.