# Some options for programs on C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, fork

I want to know can I run some compiled C program for example `main.exe` with option, that make sleep it after program work? Or can I run immediatly second program and using process, which running with `main.exe`?
I need to calculate memory of process, when I do it in background `/proc/[pid]/status` and `ps aux` show me incorrect values, because `main.exe` works so fast.
Or may be I can exec 2 programs in C using one `fork()`? Or can make option for `execv` or `execl`?

Comment: `main.exe` on linux?

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages! Please think about the idea of tagging.

Comment: @awesomeyi: Why not? Linux is not restricted to a specific filename-suffix :-)

Comment: @awesomeyi `gcc program.c -o main.exe` i don't see strange thing here

Comment: @Olaf my version of `g++` can compile my C program when I change extension of file)

Comment: It is, however, uncommon (and ugly). You really should use a more descritive name.

Comment: Beacuse that is basically gcc. However, these are still different languages. Even the same syntax may have different semantics. If you do not understand this, please read a C and C++ book.

Comment: I know C and C++, I don't write specialy Visual C++, I see c++ more popular tag than simple c because need quickly useful answers

Comment: @АлиВелиев You're not supposed to do that. I don't tag my R questions Python for quick answers...

Comment: You should add more tags. The more the better, best for completely unrelated topics, so even more people will read your post (and vote to clear and/or downvote).

Comment: Given how the question is phrased here, this is *neither* c *nor* c++. It could *maybe* apply to both.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: OP is clearly asking for C and answers can be different (once he clarifies what he actually wants to accomplish)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process

Comment: Other than being mentioned, I can't see anything "C" here. Let's just agree the question is completely unclear.

Comment: Из-за этих вот кретинов я не могу теперь задавать вопросы... Доебались до хештегов бля и заминусовали всё...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, `time` command can be used to calculate execution time, memory usage, etc

Refer http://linux.die.net/man/1/time

Usage ::

```
$ time main.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to source code of your application just insert code to send signal SIGSTOP to itself at the point you want to measure:

```
 raise( SIGSTOP );
```

then you can measure whatever you want and let program go by sending SIGCONT from outside. If you do not have such access you may try to run this process and send signal outside, for example by shell script, but you would need to play with delay:

```
#!/bin/bash
./main.exe &
sleep 0.1 # this may not work on your distro, you will need to find how to sleep subsecond
kill -SIGSTOP %1
```

Comment: @EOF good point, thanks

Comment: But if I don't have access to source, and have just compiled? sleep 0.1 not  works

Comment: @АлиВелиев that's already in the answer

Comment: How can you compile *without* access to the source?

Comment: @АлиВелиев: Unless you like race-conditions, you might want to read about `ptrace()` (where applicable).

Comment: @АлиВелиев if sleep 01. does not find a way to sleep subsecond, for example here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50722/need-a-loop-to-sleep-for-a-fraction-of-second you may try to kill without any delay.

Comment: May be my friend give me this compiled code @FelixPalmen