# Get Firefox tabs memory consumption from the command line

Tags: shell, firefox, memory, command-line-interface, monitoring

Is it possible to grab (from a shell command line or a command line tools), the memory consumption of eachs Firefox tabs ?

Example:

```
$ magiccommand
tab1 14Mb
tab2 70Mb
...
```

Comment: Pretty related: [How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/131303/1983854).

Comment: @fedorqui Nope, i do not want to get Firefox global memory consumption but per tabs. A lot of plugins exists but i want to get the stats from the command line.

Comment: At least in Chrome, every tab has a different process (`ps -ef | grep [c]hrome | wc -l` returns the number of opened tabs I have)

Comment: Unfortunatly not in Firefox (only one system process called firefox)