# How to track memory usage accurately?

Tags: go, memory-leaks

I am trying to build a small tool that will allow me to run a program and track memory usage through Go. I am using `r.exec = exec.Command(r.Command, r.CommandArgs...)` to run the command, and runtime.MemStats to track memory usage (in a separate go routine):

```
func monitorRuntime() {
    m := &runtime.MemStats{}
    f, err := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("mmem_%s.csv", getFileTimeStamp()))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    f.WriteString("Time;Allocated;Total Allocated; System Memory;Num Gc;Heap Allocated;Heap System;Heap Objects;Heap Released;\n")
    for {
        runtime.ReadMemStats(m)
        f.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;\n", getTimeStamp(), m.Alloc, m.TotalAlloc, m.Sys, m.NumGC, m.HeapAlloc, m.HeapSys, m.HeapObjects, m.HeapReleased))
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

When I tested my code with simple program that just sits there (for about 12 hours), I noticed that Go is constantly allocating more memory:
[System Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYBdb.png)
[Heap Allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFDET.png)

I did a few more tests such as running the `monitorRuntime()` function without any other code, or using pprof, such as:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
)

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Yet I still noticed that memory allocation keeps going up just like in the graphs.

How can I accurately track memory usage of the program I want to run through Go?
I know one way, which I used in the past, is to use `/proc/$PID/statm`, but that file doesn't exist in every operating system (such as MacOS or Windows)

Comment: Note that every step of that for loop is going to allocate some memory (mostly because of WriteString, iirc), and that memory will persist until garbage collection.  Saw the same thing in my own loop, which allocated a hundred or so bytes per loop iteration until garbage collection.  It's not a leak, it's just normal allocation.

Comment: @VaD: ReadMemStats is as accurate as you can get, as that shows all allocations made by the Go runtime. Maybe track the output of `gctrace` to see how memory is being collected on your system.

Comment: @Kaedys I did some research before asking that question, and I arrived to the same conclusion. Even though it occurs in simpler programs such as writing the output to stdout instead of a file, or using pprof. But I still cannot figure out how I can get accurate memory usage tracking of the command I run through Go (using `exec.Command`), I want to be able to tell if that command is leaking memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711589/2777965

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way in standard Go to get the memory usage of a program called from `exec.Command`. `runtime.ReadMemStats` only returns memory tracked by the go runtime (which, in this case, is only the file handling and sprintf).

Your best bet would be to execute platform specific commands to get memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (RedHat) the following will show memory usage:
`ps -No pid,comm,size,vsize,args:90`

Answer (score 0):

check out this library `https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/`

there example is

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v3/mem"
    // "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/mem"  // to use v2
)

func main() {
    v, _ := mem.VirtualMemory()

    // almost every return value is a struct
    fmt.Printf("Total: %v, Free:%v, UsedPercent:%f%%\n", v.Total, v.Free, v.UsedPercent)

    // convert to JSON. String() is also implemented
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

this example is managing it self maybe you can modify it, to manage the specific app you started with your app