# Memory usage in MiB/KiB by PID

Tags: bash, shell

I need command to get process memory usage in MiB or KiB by PID. I prefer the number I see in gnome-system-monitor in "Memory" column. I tried a lot of different commands but all of them give me some other numbers.

For example, I've tried `ps` with different keys. The most interesting was
`ps aux`. The RSS column is something close but number here greater than in gnome-system-monitor. A lot of answers on question similar to mine contain `top` command but it gives memory usage in percents.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you've tried and why you think it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /proc/YourPid/status

ps aux YourPid

top -p YourPid

pmap -x YourPid
```

All of them give process memory usage; top gives both percents and absolute value (RES - Resident size)

Look at [Understanding Process memory](https://techtalk.intersec.com/2013/07/memory-part-2-understanding-process-memory/) and [How to measure actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process) for more details about memory usage and monitor.