# Spring Cloud Config Server - Expected Memory Footprint Seems Large

Tags: spring-cloud-config

Spring Cloud Config Server - 1.4.2.RELEASE

Java 8

I have a vanilla Spring Cloud Config Server (POM below).
Main features used are:

- downloading config files from Git
- encryption/decryption through an SSH file

When I start it up with no memory constraints it cranks up to **7460.88 Mb**.

When I add constraints like below, it is at **3653.82 Mb**.

```
-Xms256m -Xmx256m -Xmn96m -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
```

As you can tell by my memory constraints I was expecting it to hang out around 256 Mb.

- **Was this an unrealistic expectation?**
- **Is there a way to get it down further?**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>any.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>spring-cloud-config-server</name>
  <description>Spring-Cloud-Config-Server that loads configuration from GIT for Spring Boot Applications.</description>

  <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <spring-cloud.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
          <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
  ```

Comment: I ran the same Jar locally, same config, Mac (using Oracle, commandline) vs RHEL (OpenJDK and running as a service). Couldn't run the exact same memory retrieval command, but Mac says its using 430Mb. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Ubuntu (OpenJDK, nohup) was running around 630mb. I switched RHEL to Oracle rather than OpenJDK, but it is about the same (3647.96 Mb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, believe I was calculating the memory wrong.

I was using this command originally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711589/4681044

But instead now I used the "top" command and got the percentage and used that against the total available and got 492Mb.