# Best way to measure memory percentage (total memory) of a process?

Tags: linux, performance

I know you can get the Resident set size from /proc/self/status, but would it be accurate percentage to divide it by the Total Memory found by /proc/meminfo ?

Comment: Use top Command in Terminal.
You can use top options to monitor a single process, read this page:
https://www.tecmint.com/12-top-command-examples-in-linux/

Comment: This is a more complex issue than you might think.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process is worth a read as is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process

Comment: Welcome. Did you try this on your linux box? How accurate it was? Do you have a use case?

Comment: This was pretty accurate, but the problem is now ; My senior wanted me to measure the CPU percentage during "HIGH" temperature for linux system, but he mention it would not have access to the proc files.