# How to get current process memory usage in Linux?

Tags: linux, delphi

How can my app, written in Delphi, get the memory and CPU usage of the current process when run on Linux? PSAPI can be used under Windows, but what can I use under Linux?

Comment: You just [read the file `/proc/stat` and parse its content](https://www.lazarusforum.de/viewtopic.php?p=107853#p107853). For [memory usage `/proc/smaps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1237930/4299358) may exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I measure the actual memory usage of an application or process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/how-can-i-measure-the-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process)