# Does GetSystemInfo give you the total number of virtual CPUs (i.e. hyper-threaded)?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

GetSystemInfo will give you the number of physical CPUs / cores, but I would like to know the total number of virtual CPUs. I.e. on the new Nahelam chips, they have 4 cores, but appear as 8 cpus.

If GetSystemInfo doesn't give this information, what API do I need (I've seen a function for getting number of logical processors, but it is Vista only. I need to support XP)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194(VS.85).aspx) Function
( Windows Vista, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP with SP3)

Comment: Hi, we have to support a base install of WindowsXP. I guess I'll just have to use GetSystemInfo as a backup in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Use NAPI (Win32 FAQ)