# Count Processors using C++ under Windows

Tags: c++, processors

Using unmanaged C++ on a Windows platform, is there a simple way to detect the number of processor cores my host machine has?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically find the number of cores on a machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx) to get the info you need.

ETA:

As mentioned in the question a commenter linked to, another (easier) way to do it would be via GetSystemInfo:

```
SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
GetSystemInfo( &sysinfo );

numCPU = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
```

Seems like GetLogicalProcessorInformation would give you more detailed info, but if all you need is the number of processors, GetSystemInfo would probably work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed there's an environment variable `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` on XP, but I couldn't find it on Microsoft's site. I believe this would be the easiest way, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out
[GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t getProcessorCores()
{
    DWORD process, system;
    if(GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), &process, &system))
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            if(system & (1 << i))
                count++;
        return count;
    }
    // may be we hav't PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access right
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
    GetSystemInfo( &sysinfo );
    return sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
}

size_t getAvailableProcessorCores()
{
    DWORD process, system;
    if(GetProcessAffinityMask(GetCurrentProcess(), &process, &system))
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            if(process & (1 << i))
                count++;
        return count;
    }
    // may be we hav't PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access right
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
    GetSystemInfo( &sysinfo );
    return sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
}
```