# get number of CPUs in C++ MFC application

Tags: c++, multithreading

I write a little raytracer and i'd like to query how many cpu cores (or virtual cpu cores if the cpu uses hyperthreading) the current computer offers, such that i can instanciate as many threads to get better parallel rendering.

How can I do that using C++?

thanks!

Comment: I am not sure, but looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with MFC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the number of physical processors by calling [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28VS.85%29.aspx) and checking the `dwNumberOfProcessors` field of the [`SYSTEM_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure.  You can get the number of logical processors by calling [`GetLogicalProcessorInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: BTW: GetLogicalProcessorInformation doesn't work on XP before SP3

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  It returns a [`SYSTEM_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958%28VS.85%29.aspx) struct which has a `dwNumberOfProcessors` member.

Answer (score 2):

The Win32 API function [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381%28VS.85%29.aspx) will return a [SYSTEM_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure with the information you need. Specifically, check the dwNumberOfProcessors member variable.