# Query number of CPU processors available using CUDA

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to find number of processors available in system using CUDA runtime APIs? I know using `cudaDeviceProp` structure I can gather information about particular GPU but how to gather such information about CPU core?

Answer (score 2):

CUDA doesn't run on CPU cores (are you thinking of OpenCL) so it doesn't provide any info about the CPU.

Detecting what type of cpu and how many cores would be OS specific - what platform are you on?
See [Get number of CPUs in Linux using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586405/get-number-of-cpus-in-linux-using-c)

Comment: I'm on Linux. I thought in the same way..so on CPU side can pthreads/openMP help me to query number of processors?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586405/get-number-of-cpus-in-linux-using-c

Comment: Using OpenCL  you can create a CPU Device content and query the processor count using clGetDeviceInfo() API call. This will give you the number of processors in an O/S independent way. But YMMV may vary depending on what the OpenCL implementation considers a processor.  On my Core I3 laptop I get 4 processors due to hyper-threading when its only has two physical cores.

Comment: @TimChild - but they aren't using openCL and installing it just to get the CPU count seems a little bit overkill compared to just reading /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: I'm using CUDA...so somewhere in my program I want to launch number of pthreads=number of physical core and I want this code to be platform independent.

Comment: @username_4567 - there isn't a platform independant way because it's platform dependent, code in the link for win32/linux. OpenMP/TBB will automatically determine the best number of threads