# How to get the number of cores on a machine with OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm parallelizing some work in my OCaml program (with `parmap`) but I would prefer not to hard code the number of cores into my application. Is there a way to get the number of cores at runtime? I would prefer not to add any more dependencies (nothing beyond `parmap` or JS's `core`). I have a feeling I'm over looking some simple call in stdlib...

EDIT: it doesn't have to be portable. Working on linux is good enough.

Comment: if you don't find anything else (not advocating this as a good example, but something I've hacked before) you can always parse `proc` to find it.

Comment: Ya that would be the worst case scenario...

Comment: I would either simply wrap `cpuinfo` with a clean interface (I know several libraries which do this, but not in OCaml) or try using FFI from [one from C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586405/get-number-of-cpus-in-linux-using-c).  (I know you said you preferred to avoid the second solution, but I've used something similar for profiling in OCaml before.)  Note that even that question has wide agreement that parsing `proc` isn't such a bad thing.

Comment: You probably should fork parmap and include a function to get the number of cores as an imported C function. See [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine) for details as to how to detect the number of cores in C on several platforms. Personally I would change the `Setcore` module to include that function.

Comment: Then of course push back your change upstream for inclusion :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I [once](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/caml-list/2011-09/msg00003.html) had the same question. That's what I eventually came with (I didn't want C bindings):

```
let cpu_count () = 
  try match Sys.os_type with 
  | "Win32" -> int_of_string (Sys.getenv "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS") 
  | _ ->
      let i = Unix.open_process_in "getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN" in
      let close () = ignore (Unix.close_process_in i) in
      try Scanf.fscanf i "%d" (fun n -> close (); n) with e -> close (); raise e
  with
  | Not_found | Sys_error _ | Failure _ | Scanf.Scan_failure _ 
  | End_of_file | Unix.Unix_error (_, _, _) -> 1
```

If you don't want `Unix` you could replace `open_process_in` by a `Sys.command` writing to a temporary file. Tested on linux and osx, reported to work on mingw but not on cygwin at the time.

**Update.** Note that this doesn't work on freebsd where as mentioned [here](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/pull/2186) you need to use
`sysctl -n hw.ncpu`. However since `Sys.os_type` doesn't have the right granularity you'd need to conditionalize on the result of `uname -s` whenever `Sys.os_type` is different from `Win32`.

Comment: I checked how `parmap` calculates this, and it seems the default is just `2`. :(, you may want to add your suggestion to that project. Cheers.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that in post since I've actually did try parmap's `get_default_processors` (or something like that) function and it did not work as advertised.

Comment: This doesn't return the number of *cores*. It returns the number of *processors*. If your machine has hyperthreading, you'll get (say) 36 processors even though there are only 18 cores.