# sudo permission problems in c program

Tags: c, permissions, command, sudo

I'm writing a c program which executes a series of bash shell commands to get the number of processors in the machine and assign affinity of the program accordingly. Here is my function:

```
int getNoOfCPUs()
{

    system("sudo nproc | sudo tee /home/sanuri/Desktop/tempnproc.txt");
    printf("Created temp file..... \n");
    FILE *fr;
    fr = fopen ("/home/sanuri/tempnproc.txt", "r");

    printf("Opened file..... \n");
    printf("%d",errno);
    int i=0;
    int number[3];
    do{
        if(fr==NULL){
            fr = fopen ("/home/sanuri/tempnproc.txt", "r");
        }

        number[i] = fgetc(fr);
        if( feof(fr) )
        {
            break ;
        }
        printf("%c", number[i]);
        i++;
    }while(1);

    if(fr!=NULL){
        fclose(fr);
    }
    return number; 
}
```

I'm still stuck at the fopen. Seems the file is not getting opened due to permission problems. Also I cannot run most useful commands through this c program because I must use sudo to run them and must give my password in order to proceed with the command successfully. I added myself to "sudo" group. Yet I cannot run those commands without sudo and giving my password. What is a general solution to this problem? What can I do to remove the requirement of giving password so that I can simply run the commands through the c program without sudo? It is better if the solution is general enough to make my program portable to any linux platform.

Comment: Consider having a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586405/get-number-of-cpus-in-linux-using-c

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that too :)

Answer (score 2):

First off, `sudo tee ...` will open the specified file, if it doesn't exist, as the user `root`, so you won't be able to view the file as a non-`root` user.

Second, instead of using `sudo` in your program, you should invoke your program *itself* with `sudo`. That way, if you're already running it as `root`, you won't be making unnecessary `sudo` calls.

Third, (at least, on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine), it would appear that running `nproc` doesn't require `sudo` in the first place.

Lastly, since you're using linux, you're probably better off using `popen` to capture the output of `nproc` instead of piping it to a file.

Also, you don't check the result of the second `fopen` call, which is likely to lead to a segfault.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the excellent and fast response.:) I will try all that. Wish I could up vote your answer, but not enough reputation :(