# error: implicit declaration of function 'sysconf'

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, cpu-cores

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586471/14202467), I'm trying to use `sysconf` to get the number of processors on a Linux machine:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
    {
         ...
         int CPUs = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
         ...
     }
```

However, the compiler gives me this error:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'sysconf'
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried to also add `#include <sys/sysinfo.h>` but nothing changed.

Comment: Looks OK. What version of linux? Try this on your system: `find /usr/include -name \*.h -print | xargs grep 'sysconf.*('`

Comment: Seems msys? I've this issue on msys