# Get Linux system information in C

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have to check Linux system information. I can execute system commands in C, but doing so I create a new process for every one, which is pretty expensive. I was wondering if there is a way to obtain system information without being forced to execute a shell command. I've been looking around for a while and I found nothing. Actually, I'm not even sure if it's more convenient to execute commands via Bash calling them from my C program or find a way to accomplish the tasks using only C.

Comment: Unless you run those shell commands in a loop, they're really not that expensive.

Comment: What system information?

Comment: I need informations about active processes, ram and disk usage, and so on. I have to obtain this informations frequently, for example every 10 or 30 minute, without impact too much on the system!

Comment: @user3574984 There's no significant impact to running `ps axwww` every 10 minutes. It sure makes the code a lot easier

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the number of processors on C / Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693948/how-do-i-retrieve-the-number-of-processors-on-c-linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linux exposes a *lot* of information under `/proc`. You can read the data from there. For example, `fopen` the file at `/proc/cpuinfo` and read its contents.

Answer (score 3):

A presumably less known (*and more complicated*) way to do that, is that you can also use the api interface to `sysctl`. To use it under Linux, you need to `#include <unistd.h>`, `#include <linux/sysctl.h>`. [A code example of that is available in the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sysctl):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/sysctl.h>

int _sysctl(struct __sysctl_args *args );

#define OSNAMESZ 100

int
main(void)
{
    struct __sysctl_args args;
    char osname[OSNAMESZ];
    size_t osnamelth;
    int name[] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_OSTYPE };

   memset(&args, 0, sizeof(struct __sysctl_args));
    args.name = name;
    args.nlen = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]);
    args.oldval = osname;
    args.oldlenp = &osnamelth;

   osnamelth = sizeof(osname);

   if (syscall(SYS__sysctl, &args) == -1) {
        perror("_sysctl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("This machine is running %*s\n", osnamelth, osname);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

However, the man page linked also notes:

> Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it using
>   syscall(2). Or rather... don't call it: use of this system call has
>   long been discouraged, and it is so unloved that it is likely to
>   disappear in a future kernel version. Since Linux 2.6.24, uses of this
>   system call result in warnings in the kernel log. Remove it from your
>   programs now; use the /proc/sys interface instead.
>
> This system call is available only if the kernel was configured with
>   the CONFIG_SYSCTL_SYSCALL option.

Please keep in mind that anything you can do with `sysctl()`, you can also just `read()` from `/proc/sys`. *Also note that I do understand that the usefulness of that syscall is questionable*, **I just put it here for reference**.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `sys/utsname.h` header file to get the kernel version, hostname, operating system, machine hardware name, etc. More about `sys/utsname.h` is [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/utsname.h.html). This is an example of getting the current kernel release.

```
#include <stdio.h> // I/O
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct utsname buff;
    printf("Kernel Release = %s\n", buff.release); // kernel release
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the same as using the [`uname`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/uname1.html) command. You can also use the `-a` option which stands for all information.

```
uname -r # -r stands for kernel release
```