# How many cores do I have?

Tags: c++, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically find the number of cores on a machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine)

I have a multi-threaded C++ program that runs on Windows, MacOS and Linux.  Is there an easy way to find out how many cores the machine on which I am running currently has? My system runs best when it has 1 thread for each core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this question may contain your answer:

[Programmatically find the number of cores on a machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine)

Edit: I just voted up ybungalobill's answer. I love `boost`!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.hardware_concurrency) or `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` if you have a C++0x compiler.

Answer (score 0):

On a linux system, cat /proc/cpuinfo and parse the output is one way. Dunno if it's the most efficient or not.