# POSIX equivalent of boost::thread::hardware_concurrency

Tags: c++, c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically find the number of cores on a machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine)

What is the POSIX or x86, x86-64 specific system call to determine the max number of threads the system can run without over-subscription? Thank you.

Comment: [`thread::hardware_concurrency()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.hardware_concurrency) essentially tells you the number of processor cores running. [Refer to this Stack Overflow answer to figure the number of CPUs available on a variety of platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine/150971#150971).

Comment: Unless you know you're the only process running, and that all your threads will maintain full load, the "number of threads you can run without over-subscription" is not a very well-defined concept, and can vary dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It uses C-compatible constructs, so why not just use the actual code? [libs/thread/src/*/thread.cpp]

using pthread library:

```
unsigned thread::hardware_concurrency()
{
#if defined(PTW32_VERSION) || defined(__hpux)
    return pthread_num_processors_np();
#elif defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__FreeBSD__)
    int count;
    size_t size=sizeof(count);
    return sysctlbyname("hw.ncpu",&count,&size,NULL,0)?0:count;
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_UNISTD_H) && defined(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)
    int const count=sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    return (count>0)?count:0;
#elif defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
    return get_nprocs();
#else
    return 0;
#endif
}
```

in windows:

```
unsigned thread::hardware_concurrency()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO info={{0}};
    GetSystemInfo(&info);
    return info.dwNumberOfProcessors;
}
```

Comment: For the header files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981038/error-get-nprocs-was-not-declared-in-this-scope

Comment: This is the number of logical cores, not the number of physical cores, so technically the threads would still be oversubscribed.