# How to calculate the execution time in C?

Tags: c, timing

How can I calculate the execution time in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* Core input/output operations                         */
#include <stdlib.h> /* Conversions, random numbers, memory allocation, etc. */
#include <math.h>   /* Common mathematical functions                        */
#include <time.h>   /* Converting between various date/time formats         */
#include <sys/time.h>
#define PI      3.1415926535   /* Known vaue of PI                          */
#define NDARTS     128   /* Number of darts thrown                    */
double pseudo_random(double a, double b) {
double r;  /* Random number */
r = ((b - a) * ((double) rand()/(double) RAND_MAX)) + a;
 return r;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int    n_procs,       /* Number of processors                 */
llimit,        /* Lower limit for random numbers       */
ulimit,        /* Upper limit for random numbers       */
n_circle,      /* Number of darts that hit the circle  */
i;             /* Dummy/Running index                  */
double pi_sum,        /* Sum of PI values from each WORKER    */
x,             /* x coordinate, betwen -1 & +1         */
y,             /* y coordinate, betwen -1 & +1         */
z,             /* Sum of x^2 and y^2                   */
error;         /* Error in calculation of PI           */
clock_t start_time,    /* Wall clock - start time              */
end_time;      /* Wall clock - end time                */
struct timeval stime, starttime1, endtime1;
struct timeval tv1, tv2, diff;

llimit   = -1;
ulimit   = 1;
n_circle = 0;
printf("\n  Monte Carlo method of finding PI\n\n");
printf("    Number of processors : %d\n", n_procs);
printf("    Number of darts      : %d\n\n", NDARTS);
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
gettimeofday(&stime, NULL);
srand(stime.tv_usec * stime.tv_usec * stime.tv_usec * stime.tv_usec);
for (i = 1; i <= NDARTS; i++) {
x = pseudo_random(llimit, ulimit);
y = pseudo_random(llimit, ulimit);
z = pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2);
if (z <= 1.0) {
   n_circle++;
  }
}


pi_sum = 4.0 * (double)n_circle/(double)NDARTS;
pi_sum = pi_sum / n_procs;
error = fabs((pi_sum - PI)/PI) * 100;
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
double timeval_subtract (result, x, y)
{
result = ((double)  x - (double) y ) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
double result1 = timeval_subtract(&diff, &tv1, &tv2);
printf("    Known value of  PI   : %11.10f\n", PI);
printf("    Average value of PI  : %11.10f\n", pi_sum);
printf("    Percentage Error     : %10.8f\n", error);
printf("    Time   : \n", clock() );
printf("    Start Time   : \n",&tv1);
printf("    End Time   :\n", &tv2);
printf("    Time elapsed (sec)   : \n", result1 );
 return 0;
}
```

I used timeval_subtract function and when I execute the code, I got:

```
Monte Carlo method of finding PI

Number of processors : 16372
Number of darts      : 128

Known value of  PI   : 3.1415926535
Average value of PI  : 0.0002004184
Percentage Error     : 99.99362048
Time   : 
Start Time   : 
End Time   :
Time elapsed (sec)   :
```

First, I couldn't find the mistake in finding the number of processors (I must get 1 processor).

Second "which is the most important point", Why do I get the Time, Start Time, End Time and Time elapsed empty?

Comment: I think you may want to consider using a profiler.

Comment: Please turn on your compiler's warnings. It will tell you what's wrong with the printouts and the `n_procs` thing.

Comment: clock() does not measure the time your program used to execute, but tries to return the clock cycles the cpu used (normally measured in tics or so called jiffies). But even if you convert this value to seconds (by dividing it by CLOCKS_PER_SEC, the result could differ significantly from the time the program actually used to complete. How much it differs depends on what the program does.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have adequate format strings for them, you need something starting with a '%', like:

```
printf("    Time   :%d \n", clock() );
```

Answer (score 1):

n_procs is never initialized, the 16372-value that gets printed just happens to be what was previously on the stack.

The C standard library doesn't provide functionality to query processor count or high-performance timers, so you will have to look at other means of querying this. For instance, both POSIX and Windows API provides functionality like this.

edit: See [Programmatically find the number of cores on a machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine) for how to initialize n_procs. Seeing how you use gettimeofday, you're probably on some unix-variant; "n_procs = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);" is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
printf("    Time   : %lu\n", clock() );
printf("    Start Time   : %lds %ldus\n", tv1.tv_sec, tv1.tv_usec);
printf("    End Time   : %lds %ldus\n", tv2.tv_sec, tv2.tv_usec);
```

And for:

```
double timeval_subtract (result, x, y)
```

use the following to return the time difference in micro seconds:

```
long timeval_subtract (struct timeval * result, struct timeval * x, struct timeval * y)
{
   long usec = x->tv_sec * 1000000L + x->tv_usec;
   usec -= (y->tv_sec * 1000000L + y->tv_usec);

   result->tv_sec = usec / 1000000L;
   result->tv_usec = usec % 1000000L;

   return usec;
}
```

Depending on the difference of the two dates `x` and `y` the return value of the function `timeval_subtract` (not the value represented by `result`!) might be wrong, due to an overflow.

Assuming a long is 32bit wide this overflow will occur with differences larger than 4294s, for a long having 64bit (which should be the case an 64bit machines) the overflow whould occur after much later ... ;-)

Comment: I got this error
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token in the line : 
long timeval_subtract (timeval * result, timeval * x, timeval * y)

Comment: @NUM ONE: Sry, just added the missing 'struct's.

Comment: @NUM ONE: replaced example by better solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following :

```
int     timeval_subtract ( struct timeval *result, struct timeval *x, struct timeval *y ) {

    if ( x->tv_usec < y->tv_usec ) {
            int nsec = ( y->tv_usec - x->tv_usec ) / 1000000 + 1;
            y->tv_usec -= 1000000 * nsec;
            y->tv_sec += nsec;
    }
    if (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec > 1000000) {
            int nsec = ( x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec ) / 1000000;
            y->tv_usec += 1000000 * nsec;
            y->tv_sec -= nsec;
    }

    result->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
    result->tv_usec = x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec;

    return x->tv_sec < y->tv_sec;
}

void Start ( struct timeval *timer_profiling ) {
        if ( timer_profiling == NULL )   return;
        gettimeofday ( timer_profiling , NULL );
        return;
}

void End ( struct timeval *timer_profiling , char *msg ) {
        struct timeval res;
        struct timeval now;
        gettimeofday ( &now , NULL );

        if ( msg == NULL )      return;

        timeval_subtract ( &res , &now , timer_profiling );
        sprintf ( msg , "[ %ld,%.3ld ms]" , res.tv_sec*1000 + (long)round(res.tv_usec/1000) , res.tv_usec - (long)round(res.tv_usec/1000)*1000);

        return;
}
```

Start(&s) one with an allocated timer_profiling , then retrieve the result in a string by calling End(&s,buff);

Comment: The timeval_subtract function as provided in the OP's source will not work.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right, added an alternative implementation. Thanks for pointing out !