# elapsed time in negative value

Tags: c

```
  struct timeval start, end;
  start.tv_usec = 0;
  end.tv_usec = 0;

  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

  functionA();

  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

  long t = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
  printf("Total elapsed time %ld us \n", t);
```

I am calculating the total elapsed time like this but it sometimes shows a negative value. 
What might be cause the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A related disscusion (including a solution) could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675136/how-to-calculate-the-execution-time-in-c/7675302#7675302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something along the lines of:

`long t = (end.tv_sec*1e6 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec*1e6 + start.tv_usec);`

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that there is both a seconds and micro-seconds field of that structure.  Therefore if you are simply subtracting the micro-seconds field, you could have a time that is later in seconds, but the microseconds field is less.  For instance, and end-time of 5 seconds, 100 microseconds will have a negative result compared to 4 seconds and 5000 microseconds with the subtraction method you're using.  In order to get the proper result, you have to take into account both the seconds and micro-seconds fields of the structure.  This can be done doing the following:

```
long seconds = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec;
long micro_seconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

if (micro_seconds < 0)
{
    seconds -= 1;
}

long total_micro_seconds = (seconds * 1000000) + abs(micro_seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Elapsed-Time.html):

> Data Type: **struct timeval**
>
> The `struct timeval` structure represents an elapsed time. It is declared in `sys/time.h` and has the following members:
>
> > `long int tv_sec`
> >
> > > This represents the number of whole seconds of elapsed time.
> >
> > `long int tv_usec`
> >
> > > This is the rest of the elapsed time (a fraction of a second), represented as the number of microseconds. It is always less than one million.

The only thing you're subtracting is the microseconds in `tv_usec` above the full seconds value in `tv_sec`. You need to work with both values in order to find the exact microsecond difference between the two times.