# time difference in microseconds

Tags: c, wireshark, pcap, libpcap, epoch

I have question about the EPOCH time.

I need to calculate the time difference between two packets. and I am not so sure how:

```
printf("Epoch Time: %d:%d seconds\n", header->ts.tv_sec, header->ts.tv_usec);

the first packet shows: 1396191661:164162

the second packet shows:  1396191661:164193
```

I need that variable `u_int diff_time` will contain the time difference between two packets- in microseconds.
as you can see, the difference is between packet_1 and packet_2- only in the microseconds part.

how should I calculate it if the difference not only within the tv.u_sec?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the execution time in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675136/how-to-calculate-the-execution-time-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the difference between seconds:

```
udiff = (second.tv_sec - first.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (second.tv_usec - first.tv_usec)
```

You just have to check that the difference between two packets is less than ~2000 seconds to stay in the size of a 32-bits `int`.

Comment: the difference now in EPOCH right? do I need to convert it to regular  microseconds..? or it is o.k to leave it this way..   thanks.

Comment: @user3378689 EPOCH is the name from which time is mesured, not a unit, it's January 1fst 1970 00:00:00. But in our case, we are getting the difference between 2 dates from EPOCH, so you get the result in microsecond, you don't have anything more to do. It just like if you have `X = EPOCH + T1 ; Y = EPOCH + T2`, in this case `T2 - T1` (what you have) is same as `Y - X`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two times `t1.sec`, `t1.usec`, `t2.sec` and `t2.usec` with t1 > t2, then I suppose you can calculate the difference by `(t1.sec - t2.sec) * 1000000 + (t1.usec - t2.usec)`.