# How to find the number of cores at runtime in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Does Haskell have a method for determining the number of CPU cores present on a machine at runtime?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there is such a method. Code from "Real World Haskell": http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html

```
import GHC.Conc (numCapabilities)

main = putStrLn $ "number of cores: " ++ show numCapabilities
```

Comment: Note that (as the book states) this only gives you the number of cores supplied to the RTS via `-N`, which is not necessarily equal to the number of physical cores.

Comment: It's the number of cores that Haskell will be allowed to access...which is almost certainly what the OP actually wants?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I can see use cases where a program may wish to make use of as many cores as required (without being explicitly granted permission to do so).  Alternatively, someone may wish to write a program to obtain hardware statistics.

Comment: But they *couldn't* use any more cores than the number supplied to the RTS via -N, even if they wanted to.  The second case you describe is the only other case I can imagine.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Another case is a make-like program that wants to start up N external processes, where N = number of cores, but itself uses only a single capability (with `-threaded`, so that FFI calls don't block the whole process).

Answer (score 16):

Since `base` 4.5 you can use `getNumProcessors` from [GHC.Conc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html). This is good since the number of capabilities can now be set dynamically with `setNumCapabilities` from the same.

Answer (score 6):

You could copy'n'paste [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine/3006416#3006416) into a file called `numCores` and compile it with your Haskell code. Than you can use the FFI to import its definition and use it directly in your Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Foreign.C.Types (CInt)

foreign import ccall "getNumCores" c_getNumCores :: IO CInt
getNumCores :: IO Int
getNumCores = fromEnum <$> c_getNumCores
```

Answer (score 6):

Since version 6.12, GHC RTS [includes a function `getNumberOfProcessors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/changeset/0ee0be109fd00ec629f7a2ad6a597885a0c9d5b4), which is used to implement [`+RTS -N`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/using-smp.html#parallel-options). You can access it in much the same manner as ordinary foreign functions. **Warning:** GHC-only and only works if the program was built with `-threaded`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Foreign.C.Types (CInt)

foreign import ccall "getNumberOfProcessors" c_getNumberOfProcessors :: IO CInt

main :: IO ()
main = c_getNumberOfProcessors >>= print
```

Testing:

```
$ ghc --make -threaded Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
$ ./Main                      
1
```

Answer (score -1):

It is `GHC.Conc.getNumProcessors :: IO Int`. The
`getNumCapabilities` tells how many threads are suggested to GHC (and depends on `+RTS -N` option parameter.)