# Multithreading an OpenCV Program

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Thanks for reading my post.

I have a problem with multithreading an opencv application I was hoping you guys could help me out with.

My aim is to Save 400 frames (in jpeg) from the middle of a video sequence for further examination.

I have the code running fine single threaded, but the multithreading is causing quite a lot of issues so I’m wondering if I have got the philosophy all wrong.

In terms of a schematic of what I should do, would I be best to:

Option 1 : somehow simultaneously access the single video file (or make copies?), then with individual threads cycling through the video frame by frame,  save each frame when it is between predetermined limits? E.g. thread 1 saves frames 50 to 100, thread 2 saves frames 101 to 150 etc.

Option 2 : open the file once, cycle through frame by frame then pass an individual frame to a series of unique threads to carry out a saving operation. E.g. frame 1 passed to thread 1 for saving, frame 2 to thread 2 for saving, frame 3 to thread 1,   frame 4 to thread 2 etc etc.

Option 3 : some other buffer/thread arrangement which is a better idea than the above!

I'm using visual C++ with the standard libs.

Many thanks for your help on this,

Cheers, Kay

Comment: I would try Option 1 first, that seems quite sensible, no threads will have to share data, which is the simple case (actually Option 2 might not have to share data).  But Option 1 seems more efficient, now the advice is "try both options and see which performs better ;-)  Use as many threads as cores that you have.  One would hope OpenCV has a way to specify the frame range that you want to start working with, so each thread doesn't have to start at frame 0.

Comment: Hi Chris O, thanks for your reply, Option 1 is what i have tried to do this far, but because of the errors, i was wondering if it was even possible to do this! Can threads usually access the same file? how do I find out how many threads i can have? cheers, kay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 1 is what i have tried to do this far, but because of the errors, i was wondering if it was even possible to do this! Can threads usually access the same file? how do I find out how many threads i can have?

Certainly, different threads can access the same file, but it's really a question if the supporting libraries support that.  For reading a video stream, you can use either OpenCV or ffmpeg (you can use both in the same app, ffmpeg for reading and OpenCV for processing, for example).  Haven't looked at the docs, so I'm guessing here:  either lib *should* allow multiple readers on the same file.

To find out the number of cores:

```
SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo;
GetSystemInfo( &sysinfo );
numCPU = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
```

from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine) .  You would create one thread / core as a starting point, then change the number based on your performance needs and on actual testing.