# Logical core programming in .net

Tags: c#, c

Actually i have a visual c# program for matrix multiplication that uses all the logical cores in i3 processor but i want to know how to implement in c and its explaination. annd the program is,

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MatrixMultiplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        #region Sequential_Loop

        private static void MultiplyMatricesSequential(double[,] matA, double[,] matB,
                                                       double[,] result)
        {
            int matACols = matA.GetLength(1);
            int matBCols = matB.GetLength(1);
            int matARows = matA.GetLength(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < matARows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matBCols; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < matACols; k++)
                    {
                        result[i, j] += matA[i, k]*matB[k, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Parallel_Loop

        private static void MultiplyMatricesParallel(double[,] matA, double[,] matB, double[,] result)
        {
            int matACols = matA.GetLength(1);
            int matBCols = matB.GetLength(1);
            int matARows = matA.GetLength(0);

            // A basic matrix multiplication.
            // Parallelize the outer loop to partition the source array by rows.
            Parallel.For(0, matARows, i =>
                                          {
                                              for (int j = 0; j < matBCols; j++)
                                              {
                                                  // Use a temporary to improve parallel performance.
                                                  double temp = 0;
                                                  for (int k = 0; k < matACols; k++)
                                                  {
                                                      temp += matA[i, k]*matB[k, j];
                                                  }
                                                  result[i, j] = temp;
                                              }
                                          }); // Parallel.For
        }

        #endregion

        #region Main

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set up matrices. Use small values to better view 
            // result matrix. Increase the counts to see greater 
            // speedup in the parallel loop vs. the sequential loop.
            int colCount = 800;
            int rowCount = 800;
            int colCount2 = 800;
            double[,] m1 = InitializeMatrix(rowCount, colCount);
            double[,] m2 = InitializeMatrix(colCount, colCount2);
            var result = new double[rowCount,colCount2];

            // First do the sequential version.
            Console.WriteLine("Executing sequential loop...");
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            MultiplyMatricesSequential(m1, m2, result);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Sequential loop time in milliseconds: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // For the skeptics.
            OfferToPrint(rowCount, colCount2, result);

            // Reset timer and results matrix. 
            stopwatch.Reset();
            result = new double[rowCount,colCount2];

            // Do the parallel loop.
            Console.WriteLine("Executing parallel loop...");
            stopwatch.Start();
            MultiplyMatricesParallel(m1, m2, result);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Parallel loop time in milliseconds: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            OfferToPrint(rowCount, colCount2, result);

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Helper_Methods

        private static double[,] InitializeMatrix(int rows, int cols)
        {
            var matrix = new double[rows,cols];

            var r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = r.Next(100);
                }
            }
            return matrix;
        }

        private static void OfferToPrint(int rowCount, int colCount, double[,] matrix)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computation complete. Print results? y/n");
            char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y')
            {
                Console.WindowWidth = 180;
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int x = 0; x < rowCount; x++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ROW {0}: ", x);
                    for (int y = 0; y < colCount; y++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:#.##} ", matrix[x, y]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read up C programming books, basically just convert the syntax to C. the input/output syntax are scanf and printf. For array, use [][] instead of [,] for 2D array. The rest is quite similar.

Comment: @rcs actually there is no C alternative to Parallel.For that I am aware of. The parallel case is not as trivial as merely converting the code.

Comment: @user2786161 you might want to edit your code and remove the serial implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is a "delightfully parallel" problem, i.e. it can be trivially parallelized, since each cell in the result array is independent of the value of any other cell.

The parallel solution in your code could be even further parallelized by partitioning on cells not on rows, e.g. by numbering each cell in the result matrix as j + i*matBCols (**CAVEAT** I didn't check this code, I may have switched some index, please comment if you spot an error):

```
private static void MultiplyMatricesParallel(double[,] matA, double[,] matB, double[,] result)
{
    int matACols = matA.GetLength(1);
    int matBCols = matB.GetLength(1);
    int matARows = matA.GetLength(0);

    // A basic matrix multiplication.
    // Parallelize the outer loop to partition the source array by rows.
    Parallel.For(0, matARows*matBCols, ij =>
                                  {
                                      i = ij / matBCols;
                                      j = ij % matBCols;

                                      // Use a temporary to improve parallel performance.
                                      double temp = 0;
                                      for (int k = 0; k < matACols; k++)
                                      {
                                          temp += matA[i, k]*matB[k, j];
                                      }
                                      result[i, j] = temp;

                                  }); // Parallel.For
}
```

The trivial way to make this work in C would be create a thread for each cell in the result matrix, but this would be wasteful and sub-optimal this is because Parallel.For is actually doing some under the scenes calculations in order to optimize the speed of the calculation.

In the best case scenario we want to partition the array so each core gets an equal share of the array multiplication. In the Task Parallel Library (TPL) which contains Parallel.For  each cell computation (in my example) or row computation (in the original) is converted into a task. Parallel.For takes into account the number of cores and assigns worker threads to each core, trying to maintain a balance of work between the cores and a minimum amount of threads. In the perfect scenario with 2 cores, this would be two threads with half the matrix multiplication each. However the TPL has dynamic balancing built in.

If for instance one of the cores becomes busy (e.g. running another process) or one of the worker threads becomes blocked (e.g. waiting for a block from virtual memory), then the TPL will spawn more threads and re-balance the work load.

You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335070.aspx).

What I'm trying to say is that replicating the work of Parallel.For in C is not a trivial task. For the case of matrix multiplication you can get a good facsimile by forgoing the dynamic reallocation of tasks. Simply create as many threads as CPU cores with core affinity for each thread and partition the matrix equally between them.

In windows you can get the number of cores with: `GetSystemInfo` (or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine) for other options), and create threads with core affinity using `CreateThread` and `SetThreadAffinityMask`.