# run a c++ programme with a specifc number of cores, detect it in the programme

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I am working on parallel programming on c++ (with Mac and linux) and I want to know if there is a way to detect the number of cores assigned to this program in c++98. Thank you.

Comment: The part of the question is not yet answer... How do we assign number of cores to a parallelized c++ computation...

Comment: I will undo the [duplicate vote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355).  Please [edit] your question to clarify what is unique about it.

Comment: Are you are working on a cluster-type environment with a job queue? If you are developing for a single machine with multiple cores, and no job scheduler, then the OS shares the CPU(s) amongst processes and the number of processes you should run should be roughly the number of CPUs in the system. But I'm not aware of assignment of cores in normal use. I could just be ignorant though.

Comment: There will be no *portable standard c++98* way to do this