# Multithreading set number of threads via commandline arguments or

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Edit/Solved**: Joachim Pileborg's answer did the job for me. THX

Please be gentle as this is my first question.

I am actual lerning and playing with c++ in particular threading. I looked for an answer (and it would astonish me if there is not allready one out there, but i wasn't able to find it).

So back to topic:
My "play" code looks something like this (Console application)

```
void foo(){
//do something
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::thread t[threadcount];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadcount; ++i) {
            t[i] = std::thread(foo);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threadcount; ++i) {
            t[i].join();
        }
}
```

Is it possible to set the value of threadcount through argv?
If not could someone please give me a short snippet on how to implement

```
std::thread::hardware_concurrency()
```

as the threadcount, because also there Visualstudio gives me an error when setting

```
const int threadcount = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As the number of threas is to be controlled by `threadcount`, setting it from the command line can be implemented by adding

```
int threadcount = atoi(argv[1]);
```

to the implementation. Some error checking could be done, e.g. reporting an error on a non-positive number of threads.

If the number of threads is to be determined programmatically, depending on the specific platform, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150355/programmatically-find-the-number-of-cores-on-a-machine) could be interesting.

Comment: Yes that was basicly one of my ideas, but when doing this, Visualstudio gives me:
C2057: expected constant expression

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the error seems unrelated; have you tried omitting `const` from the declaration of `threadcount`?

Comment: @OniuoniuOnuoinuo C++ doesn't have [*variable-length arrays*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) so you can't create an array using a variable as size. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.