# How to specify how many cores program can use C++ win/linux

Tags: c++, multicore

I am writing a multi-platform software. And I want to make configurable value number_of_cores_to_use that will be number from 1 to 4. 1- program will use 1 core,2-2 cores etc.

How can I do that with c++. Some function with option to run thread on specified core?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you mean; as in an internal variable that tells your program how many threads it can spawn? Or a variable that somehow restricts your process to n-cores?

Comment: AFAIK nothing in the standard library. You probably need to specify an OS

Comment: only related to the OS you use. Win-API, posix, ... Nothing related to c++ directly

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/150355/1025391 ?

Comment: Why do you even want to do that? The OS is usually fully capable of making such decisions on its own, which usually results in much better performance than forcing threads to fixed CPU cores. If you really feel this is necessary, I would strongly recommend not adding this as a feature to the application but rather use the appropriate OS tools to do that.

Otherwise, just make your application to launch only so many threads as it is supposed to use cores. One thread will always use one core.

Comment: Do you mean something like:
'export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4' (Linux terminal),
or from inside the code 'omp_set_num_threads(maxThreads);' ?
(These examples are for OpenMP).
With these examples you can specify the number of cores that your application will use.

Comment: @MartinHierholzer It's useful when you don't want an application to hog all your cores

Comment: You can't. The OS decides that for your. The closest you can get to that in Windows is by utilizing the [SetThreadAffinityMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: As for Linux this might be useful: https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity

Comment: @passer-by The question is: why at all, and why from inside the application? Better lower the application's priority, if you want to improve the performance of other applications.