# How to check the number of cores used by docker container?

Tags: docker, containers

I have been working with Docker for a while now, I have installed docker and launched a container using

```
docker run -it --cpuset-cpus=0 ubuntu
```

When I log into the docker console and run

```
grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

It shows 3 which are the number of cores I have on my host machine.

Any idea on how to restrict the resources to the container and how to verify the restrictions??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many CPUs does my docker container have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151296/how-many-cpus-does-my-docker-container-have)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Containers aren't complete virtual machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-normal-virtual-machine?rq=1). Some kernel resources will still appear as they do on the host.

In this case, `--cpuset-cpus=0` modifies the resources the container cgroup has access to which is available in `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus`. Not what the VM and container have in `/proc/cpuinfo`.

One way to verify is to run the [`stress-ng`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/stress-ng) tool in a container:

Using 1 cpu will be pinned at 1 core (1 / 3 cores in use, 100% or 33% depending on what tool you use):

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus=0 deployable/stress -c 3
```

This will use 2 cores (2 / 3 cores, 200%/66%):

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus=0,2 deployable/stress -c 3
```

This will use 3 ( 3 / 3 cores, 300%/100%):

```
docker run deployable/stress -c 3
```

Memory limits are another area that don't appear in kernel stats

```
$ docker run -m 64M busybox free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3443       2500        943        173        261       1858
-/+ buffers/cache:        379       3063
Swap:         1023          0       1023
```

[yamaneks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547987/1318694) includes the [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20770).

Answer (score 13):

The issue has been already raised in [#20770](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20770). The file `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus` reflects the correct output.

The `cpuset-cpus` is taking effect however is not being reflected in `/proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 8):

```
docker inspect <container_name>
```

will  give the details of the container launched u have to check for "CpusetCpus" in there and then u will find the details.

Comment: Can use `docker inspect <container_name> | grep CpusetCpus` to filter the output

Comment: If this value is blank?

Answer (score -3):

it should be in double quotes --cpuset-cpus="", --cpuset-cpus="0" means it make use of cpu0.

Comment: # docker run -it --cpuset-cpus="0" 20c44cd7596f "/bin/bash"

root@c44351fd21a7:/# grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
3
No change

Comment: Quotes are only required if you have spaces or other shell special characters in the argument.