# Find CPU core count for apple m1/m2?

Tags: c, apple-m1

I see questions asking for apple gpu core count. I'd simply like to know how in C I can find how many cores are on the system? I know the apple m2 has 8 but the M1 appears to have 8 or more. Also I hear the big cores might be disabled in a battery efficient mode. I don't need to know how to detect that but that might be useful

Comment: It this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/150355/20017547

Comment: @Haris: Yes that'd work. I just remembered I do use C++ in some places in my mac build so I can use that c++11 solution

Comment: It has solutions in ```C```.