# Monitor memory usage inside your own process

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, windows-mobile

Let's put Heisenberg aside for a brief moment.

How would I go about to, from within my own process, monitor how much memory this process is using?

(I might have under-specified the question on purpose, dreaming of creative answers...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quassnoi is correct - but it also might be worth checking our this question:

[How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) which includes code examples

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GetProcessMemoryInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx)

`WorkingSetSize` in `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` seems to be what you want.

Comment: Would have been great - outside of Windows Mobile (where I operate). Thanks, for the tip, though.