# Get CPU and memory usage of application programmatically on HPUX

Tags: c++, unix, diagnostics

Is there a way to get the CPU and memory usage programmatically (C++) of an application on HPUX?

Answer (score 1):

[How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

Answers are given for Windows and Linux, not HPUX, but the Linux version might lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

HP-UX supports [getrusage()](http://docs.hp.com/en/B3921-90010/getrusage.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the numbers for a different process, use [`pstat_getproc()`](http://docs.hp.com/en/B2355-90130/pstat.2.html).