# How to get the size of available system memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, diagnostics

Is it possible to get the size of system available memory in C#.NET? if yes how?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.totalphysicalmemory.aspx).

Right-click your project, Add Reference, select `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

Comment: It is a .NET framework class, available in any version since 2.0. The namespace name is irrelevant.

Comment: @JeffreyKevinPry - It doesn't mean your doing VB.NET or anything. It's just another useful Framework library that in this case has wrapped up functionality that is appropriate to use. It's not crossing any C# purist line; it's just using the full potential of .NET.

Comment: If you don't like using the VB wrapper, you can wrap the same native method it uses: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GlobalMemoryStatusEx.html

Comment: I'am on C# and .NET 4.5.2: `new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory`

Comment: For C#, just add a reference to your project for Microsoft.VisualBasic.  Then, add       using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;  To the top of the file where you'll be using it.  Then, you can use it as    new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory.

Answer (score 29):

This answer is based on Hans Passant's. The required property is AvailablePhysicalMemory actually. and it (and TotalPhysicalMemory and others) are instance variables, so it should be

```
new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory
```

It works in C#, but I wonder why [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127826.aspx) says that for C#, "This language is not supported or no code example is available."

Comment: No- because its part of the `My` Namespace used in Visual Basic! Not C# - Including this Visual Basic dll will expose these short cuts that are so nice in VB.NET; And people who go into C# after VB start to miss that. Nice answer +1

Comment: Thx! Using this version now.

Answer (score 20):

From [EggHeadCafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/39297eb1-dc9f-49b1-9598-576c706f03cf/c--get-system-memory-information.aspx) after googling for 'c# system memory'

You will need to add a reference to System.Management

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace MemInfo
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjectQuery winQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration");

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(winQuery);

            foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Total Space = " + item["TotalPageFileSpace"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Total Physical Memory = " + item["TotalPhysicalMemory"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Total Virtual Memory = " + item["TotalVirtualMemory"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Available Virtual Memory = " + item["AvailableVirtualMemory"]);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

Total Space = 4033036

Total Physical Memory = 2095172

Total Virtual Memory = 1933904

Available Virtual Memory = 116280

Comment: Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration is not available from Vista onwards. Replace with CIM_OperatingSystem and use TotalVisibleMemorySize, TotalVirtualMemorySize etc. instead. The code above throws an exception on Win7 and probably on Vista as well.

Comment: Following on from @Canacourse's comment, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387937(v=vs.85).aspx for information on the CIM_OperatingSystem class.

Answer (score 14):

```
var performance = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
var memory = performance.NextValue();
```

Comment: FYI "Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied" happens unless you explicitly grant permission.

Answer (score 2):

Using the performance counters accessible via System.Diagnostics will be one option.

Refer http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4612-Find-Memory-usage-CPU-usage.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A piece of codes:

```
 System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter ramCounter;     
 ramCounter = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes"); //"Available MBytes" for MB
 string getAvailableRAMInBytes = ramCounter.NextValue() + "byte";
```

Comment: Hey! I like your code example much more, as the variable names are more "talkative" ;-)