# My program Memory used 100% ! How can I know what uses so much memory?

Tags: c#

We have a program written in C#, used as a server. It's a Windows service. This program often uses all the memory of the machine， but I do not know what causes this. What can I do?

my program used as a Official server already,and i can not restart it Casual ，so i can not use any tools ,because tool need restart my program and can not Attach to Process. And i do not know potentially harmful code ,because my program have so many code.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the application? And if so, did you understand, what it is doing?

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried.

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak... Does it happen at a certain part of the application? You could try profiling it depending on tools you have or on very basic level running Task Manager and watch memory use during certain operations to see if you can see where memory leak appears (i.e. during a certain phase of the service).

Comment: Use a memory profiler like .Net Memory Profiler. http://memprofiler.com/

Comment: Show us some of the code that you think may be causing this.  Or if you don't know which part is causing the memory usage then start chopping pieces out (comment out large parts) and see when the performance improves

Comment: Visual Studio Performance Analyzer (Analyze > Start Performance Analysis)

Comment: my program used as a Official server already,and i can not restart it Casual ，so i can not use any tools ,because tool need restart my program and can not Attach to Process. And i do not know potentially harmful code ,because my program have so many code.

Comment: "i do not know potentially harmful code ,because my program have so many code." Then it's too late for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are dfferent tools which can help you to investigate issues like this.

The most simple is a loging in start of potentially harmful code and in process of that.

If you have no idea, were that code could be, you may look on :

[MemoryProfiler from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

or free one from MS, like :

[MS Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273), but it's not so intuitive to use.

Comment: yes,I try that already ，but, all tools can not Attach to Process ，must restart the promgram. and I want to writter log but C# can not get the memory use of a thread !

Comment: @user2538281: are ou sure that JetBrains is not able "connect to process" ?

Comment: yes I use it ,it only can used when i start my program with it ,can not Attach to Process, does not it? i used dotTrace Profiler 3.1

Comment: seems actually you are right, *there is* attach process but for performance and not memory. Can you run your web service like and ordinary application (timer ??) and profile it like that?

Comment: i can do that change it to ordinary  application,but there is tow Problem。1.i must used it in Official environment，because in our Test Environment we can not Reappear this，we do not know what Operate user did can cause this. 2.if i use it in  Official environment ,i am not allowed to use profile tools ，maybe profiler tools will cuase Bad performance

Comment: @user2538281: I'm afraid, at this point, the only choice you have is logging. You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296211/how-to-get-the-size-of-available-system-memory to check at what moments in icreases, and may be only for debug reasons, you can, in case when you rich the limit, show a message to a user, so they call you, and you look on logs. There is no easy solution

Comment: yes，it is a no easy solution,and it is our Last resort，i have think about it. but i think it L ow success rate about that plan，our program have High concurrency，this plan may help us to Refine。 thank  you very much

Comment: by the way i know windebug can help this, but it hard to use.

Comment: @user2538281: you can sue remote debuging of VS too, if you are able to connect to remote machine and upload there PDB. But as much as I understood, you are not able to connect to that machine.

Comment: if the remote machine as server work well i can not debug it ,but if it down i can use it ,are you sure i can use  remote debuging of VS to see something when my server's memory full? how can i do that?

Comment: I don't know if you can or not, cause you need to run remote on that machine that hosts requests from VS. Look here for detailed description of steps for setup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bt727f1t.aspx

Comment: i think it is not useful for me,i want to konw who used the memory ,but remote debug can not help me do this. thank you ！

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [Ants memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/). I think it is very easy and intuitive to use though quite powerful tool. It's not free, but it's worth it if you have memory issues.

Comment: can it Attach to Process?

Comment: Both IIS and standalone as far as I remember, you can check their web site for specs