# What should be the right SplitSize (Chunk) for a external merge sort?

Tags: c#, io, mergesort

I am using an existing code of External Merge Sort algorithm.

This algorithm must be able to handle large files ( i.e. 10GB, 20 GB, and even more )
The available memory can be 15 GB or 10GB ( as it has to run on any modern-day computers. So I do not have any constraint of having 1 GB or 2 GB RAM ).

The existing Snippet code is the following.

```
public class ExternalMergeSortSplitOptions
{   
   /// Size of unsorted file (chunk) (in bytes)

   public int FileSize { get; init; } = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
   public char NewLineSeparator { get; init; } = '\n';
}
```

and the following code is used for Splitting the entire large file into multiple chunks. But this number of chunks (which will be converted to unsorted files) will be too large in numbers and take almost 30-40 mins just in the splitting process. Therefore the existing policy for splitting the files with specified Split.FileSize is not appropriate.

```
private async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<string>> SplitFile(
    Stream sourceStream,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var fileSize = _options.Split.FileSize;
    var buffer = new byte[fileSize];
    var extraBuffer = new List<byte>();
    var filenames = new List<string>();
    var totalFiles = Math.Ceiling(sourceStream.Length / (double)_options.Split.FileSize);  /// -> This line could generate 6K files if the provided size of the original file is 20 GB or similar....

    await using (sourceStream)
    {
        var currentFile = 0L;
        while (sourceStream.Position < sourceStream.Length)
        {
           ...................
           ................................................
        }
    }
```

Question: Can we convert the policy so the code can compute the number of files in a reasonable range? (i.e. by asking for free space in RAM and then accordingly the number of Chunks each having a size of equal size comparable to free RAM ).
Thanks

Comment: Do you have at least control over the complete PC? So you know there isn't running other stuff on that machine concurrently? If not don't assume you can rely on that free RAM measurement looking forward in time.  For ease of implementation and safe concurrent usage you might strife for a value derived from the installed RAM minus of free headroom for other process to use and have a look at your algorithm if the implementation has a preference for a certain MIN size and a tendency where even more RAM only slightly helps.

Comment: So try to find that sweet spot where you don't end up using predominantly the Swap File and try be a good citizens that does not hinder other processes to run effectly.

Comment: So, there is no dynamic and automatic calculation that we could perform to make Chunk Size for splitting large file into smaller files?

Comment: Are you asking how much you can safely load into ram at once without causing swap? See [How to get the size of available system memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296211/how-to-get-the-size-of-available-system-memory), that describes how to get the total ram and available ram. Note that there are some inherent limits to the number of items in an array, so to keep it simple you might just use `Array.MaxLength`.

Answer (score 0):

2 MB is too small. GNU sort for text files defaults to about 75% of available physical memory. It is C code that sorts an array of pointers to records for the initial pass that creates a set of sorted temporary files, which doesn't require much memory for a second array of pointers to records, so most of that 75% of memory is for a file buffer. I don't know if it is possible to do something equivalent to this in C#, so the amount of memory used for a file buffer would need to be adjusted.

GNU sort uses a K-way merge for the temporary files, defaulting K to 16, intended for hard drives. If using faster SSD drives, K should probably be smaller.

The source code is large (over 4000 lines) due to all the options.

https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sort.c